# Internet Explorer 8 can't see upper variables

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a big problem in front of me. I have to build soft that works on every modern browser and... IE8. 
Internet explorer can't see variables declared before function.

```
Model.something = function() {
  var someVariable = "something";
  (...)
  function process(err, data) {                 
    console.log(someVariable);     //internet explorer can't see this variable
  };
};
```

In every browser even in documentation I have, that JS see variables declared before.
In IE8, this rule doesn't exist, anyone have any simple ideas? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you mean? What happens? (and what does not happen)

Comment: function process, can't see variable declared before. Everything see it. node.js, Chrome, Firefox, IE10++, but not IE8.

Comment: Define "see it" is it undefined? Does it throw an error? Does it make your computer explode? :)

Comment: That's not true. Just tested in IE8, it 'sees' everything

Comment: I will try another approach. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes it is undefined and script can't go on.

Comment: Whatever your problem is, it is not in the sample of code you provided. There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I am 100% confident that this would work in every js engine, I do not have a window machine here but something else is hapenning here

Comment: @ganmor see jonathan.cone's answer. `console` is undefined in IE8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE8 isn't complaining about someVariable. It's complaining about console, which is undefined in IE8. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8) for more details.

Comment: It is ***BAD PRACTICE*** to use `console.log`s in production code for this exact reason.