# ajax jquery not post in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a problem with post data in jquery

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?=base_url();?>cart/add_product1',
    async: false,
    data: {
        job_id: item.job_id,
        quantity: item.quantity,
        price: item.price,
        media_code: item.media_code,
        product_id: item.layout_code,
        product_name: item.product_name,
        reedit_url: item.reedit_url,
        thumb_url: item.thumb_url
    },
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log('done!');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
})
```

I tried many thing, like add cache: flase, and added timestamp to the link but the problem is still

The code is work good in the other browsers

The code for the add_product1 function is:

```
public function add_product1 ()
{
    print_r($_POST);    
}
```

But the result is : Array()

Your help please

Thank you

Comment: Whats the problem? Are you using jQuery 2.x? In 2.x there is no support for IEs older that IE9.

Comment: Does this run in the browser's console? Does the AJAX request just not happen or it does, but doesn't do what you want it to?

Comment: Are you getting 304 status codes?

Comment: check this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: @theHacker the problem that in the add_product function when i try to print the POST it's empty, I'm using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Comment: @AymanSafadi yes in the browser's console i get empty data

Comment: @ChrisWillard no, i get 200 status code

Comment: @SNAG the console is working fine. I will add the add_product1 function

Comment: What version of IE are using. Sounds like it's modern enough to support console commands. Can you press F12 to open the IE console and then refresh to the page and run you code.

Comment: Where are all of these variables set (job_id: item.job_id, etc)?  Can confirm they're being set correctly?

Comment: I'm using IE11, but i tried it also in 10. I looking to the cosole during processing the code, i get empty array

Comment: @ChrisWillard yes, it's working correctly, because the page work fine in the other browsers !!

Comment: @dr_sd2001 Obviously it's not working correctly.

Comment: Some other part of your code, or even markup, may be causing an error that does not allow control to reach this code. Can you isolate this piece of code and test it. I believe it should work fine, confirming that the problem may be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 data: {
        "job_id": item.job_id,
        "quantity": item.quantity,
        "price": item.price,
        "media_code": item.media_code,
        "product_id": item.layout_code,
        "product_name": item.product_name,
        "reedit_url": item.reedit_url,
        "thumb_url": item.thumb_url
    },
```

Not really sure if this is the problem but it might be an IE quirk

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the variable item not defined.
In IE should add var before the variable, but the other browsers ignoring this.
My code was like this:

```
item = data.item[0];
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: "POST",
url: '<?=base_url();?>cart/add_product1',
async: false,
data: {
    job_id: item.job_id,
    quantity: item.quantity,
    price: item.price,
    media_code: item.media_code,
    product_id: item.layout_code,
    product_name: item.product_name,
    reedit_url: item.reedit_url,
    thumb_url: item.thumb_url
},
success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('done!');
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

})

I changed it to this:

```
var item = data.item[0];
$.ajax({
cache: false,
type: "POST",
url: '<?=base_url();?>cart/add_product1',
async: false,
data: {
    job_id: item.job_id,
    quantity: item.quantity,
    price: item.price,
    media_code: item.media_code,
    product_id: item.layout_code,
    product_name: item.product_name,
    reedit_url: item.reedit_url,
    thumb_url: item.thumb_url
},
success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('done!');
},
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

})