# Why use angular's $log instead of console.log?

Tags: angularjs, logging

I understand it is a best practice in angular to use `$log` instead of `console.log`.
However, I can't find good documentation explaining the reasons.  Why should a developer use `$log`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

`$log` first checks if the browser supports `console.log` (IE 8, for example, doesn't). This prevents errors being displayed on IE 8. Note: this doesn't mean it will log anything on IE 8, it simply means it won't throw the error.

Next to that, it also allows you to [decorate](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators) and mock `$log` for extending and testing purposes, if you are so inclined. You could for example decorate it to log to an array for IE 8 support.

A bonus feature: if you pass it a JavaScript `Error` instance, it will attempt to format it nicely. This can be found out by reading the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/log.js#L134).

**EDIT:** "It is not that IE 8 doesn't support console.log. It just doesn't create the console object until the dev tools are opened." See comments below for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for directing me to the source code. I'm learning that's frequently the place to go.

Comment: I figured there must be more than just avoiding missing console.  There's not much, but the decorator tip and bonus feature you mention are good to know.

Comment: +1 I think it's important to note that it is not that IE 8 doesn't support `console.log`. It just doesn't create the `console` object until the dev tools are opened. `console.log` is a supported in IE 8 as long as the dev tools are open. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8) question as a reference...

Comment: Using $log has a downside as well: if you use console.log you can see the file and the line number of the actual logging. With $log it will always show angular.js as the source of the log in your console.

Comment: It's 3 characters shorter ;)

Comment: Another bonus, it allows you to turn off debug logging in production, with $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);

Answer (score 10):

Just to complete [*@Steve's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24185961/4927984) (which is correct), `$log` also has the advantage of being **turned off**. Using this code you can disable the logging from [`$log`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$log):

```
app.config(function($logProvider) {
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

This is very handy if you want to disable all logs at once, rather than delete them line by line manually.

Comment: This will only turn off $log.debug(), but not the other log-levels.

Comment: Thats a good point, for what use are your log ? i think debug should be the most used one, the others to bring more information when its really needed.