# AngularJS: What's the difference between $log and console.log?

Tags: angularjs, error-handling

I was going through the `angularJs` doc and came to know about `log`, `warn`, `error` etc. Now to see the output we need to open the console, so my question are

**if already `console.log()` is there to see the errors in console, then what is the use of `$log`, where is the place/scenerio that I must involve the use of `$log` in my `angularJs application`.**

How can I make use of $log to store information in file about my logging activities.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/log.js#L3

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185847/why-use-angulars-log-instead-of-console-log

Comment: They are also asking if $log can be used to log to a file.

Answer (score 3):

Well, basic difference is **$log** is the AngularJs implementation of logging and a lot more than just spitting bits of strings and data to console, whereas **console.log()** is basic java script.

You pass $log as a service to your controllers, factories and other services. The plus about using $log is that you can extend and customize it.

For starters, I really like this for when I have to check what controller loaded and where things failed in a big application I can do so, by **$log.info()**:

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$logProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $logProvider)
{
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(isDebugMode);
}]);
```

See the $logProvider that enables or disables logging depending on environment.

A lot more on extending the existing logger:

- [Here](https://cmatskas.com/logging-with-angularjs-extending-the-built-in-logger/)
- [And Here](http://engineering.talis.com/articles/client-side-error-logging/)