# $resource returning empty json in IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, factory

I have created an angularjs application which uses $resource, here UserType.customDelete factory. after executing the server will return either `[{"0":"T"}]` or `[{"0":"F"}]`, The application is working fine in all browser except IE8, in IE8 i am getting  `[{}]` , but in all other browser even in IE9  i am getting `[{"0":"T"}]`

can anyone please give me some solution for this

```
UserType.customDelete({
    uid : user.uid,
    action : 'remove'
}, function(data)
    {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     if(data[0][0] === "T")
     {
       console.log('success');
     }
     else
     {
      console.log('failure');
     }

    }, function(error) {

});
```

**modals.js**

```
angular.module('users', ['ngResource'])

.constant('OPTIONS',
{
    query:
    {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true
    },
    customDelete:
    {
        method: 'POST',
        isArray: true
    }
})

.factory('UserType', function($resource, OPTIONS)
{
    return $resource('rest/users/:uid/:action',
    {
        uid: "@uid",
        action: "@action"
    }, OPTIONS);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the "Console.log" lines.
In ie8, console.log is only available after you have opened the Developer Tools.

[Same problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8)

Comment: even if we put alert also in IE8 its returning `[{}]`

Comment: @AlexMan wich version of angularjs do you use ?