# AngularJS v1.2.16 bug when using IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This piece of code :

```
  if (window.angular.bootstrap) {
    //AngularJS is already loaded, so we can return here...
    console.log('WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.');
    return;
  }
```

is contained in AngularJS version 1.2.26 and causing an issue for IE. Error message is "console is undefined". My fix is just to remove `console.log` ?

What is meaning of `window.angular.bootstrap` ?

Comment: What version of IE? This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690251/what-happened-to-console-log-in-ie8

Comment: I believe you are loading angular more than once (it's written on the piece of code). If you do not load angular more than once, then you'll be fine.

Comment: use a polyfill for `console` for older IE versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, support of the `console` object and specifically `console.log` is not good for some versions IE, so that is why you are getting that error. There are many polyfills for logging, [such as this one](https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill). Although, that is not your issue.

The reason you are even running this code in the first place, is because `window.angular.bootstrap` is **not** null or undefined, which implies you are loading Angular JS more than once.