# Write formatted JSON in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webhooks

I'm using Node.js to POST JSON to PostBin but the data is being wrongly formated (as you can see here: http://www.postbin.org/1cpndqw).

This is the code I'm using for tesT:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'www.postbin.org',
  port: 80,
  path: '/1cpndqw',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.write(JSON.stringify({ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, null, 4));
req.end();
```

Comment: `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}` did you fix your issue? It seems like you got the data posted correctly.

Comment: The data is correct but "ugly", I want to send like this, easier to understand: http://www.postbin.org/1ijyltn#xa6rim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, primarily because JSON doesn't care how it's formatted, and you aren't doing any formatting yourself.  What you need is a javascript prettyprinter, if you care, but the first question is "Why do you care?"

Here's a [prettyprinting](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577549-nicerest-pretty-print-json-output/) code from the Javascript Recipes.

Actually there's a whole bunch of different examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130404/javascript-data-formatting-pretty-printer) on SO.

*UPDATE*

Okay, so now it's doing what you want, let's ask if you're doing the right thing.  As several people have pointed out, you needn't transmit those extra newlines and tabs, or spaces; the efficiency cost is small, probably in the neighborhood of 2-5 percent, but you never know when you might need a couple percent.

On the other hand, I agree completely that it's a lot more convenient to be able to read the JSON output as prettyprinted text.  But there's another solution -- you're still probably using a browser to look at these results, so instead of prettyprinting it for transmission, use a client-side prettyprinter.  I use [JSONView for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) and [JSONView](http://jsonview.com/) in Firefox.  Many debuggers will also prettyprint the JSON results for you as well.

Comment: For transmission purposes, you don't want to be sending/receiving the extra formatting data.  The JSON with extra whitespace means nothing different to the machine... it only matters to a human that needs to understand it.  Ideally, you only want to pretty print it when you actually have a person that needs to look at it.

Comment: @donald why do you care about how it looks? JSON is raw data. You do not care about whitespace.

Comment: IT worked as: console.log(JSON.stringify({ a:1, b:2, c:3 }, null, '\t')); in the console, but still, PostBin does not make it right. Maybe it's their problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 354):

Use `JSON.stringify(object, null, 4)` where `4` is the number of spaces to use as the unit of indentation. You can also use `"\t"` if you want tabs. This is actually [part of the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12.3), and is [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Wow, thanks! I wonder why this isn't documented anymore. I assumed it wasn't available.

Comment: Yeah, it's odd. Maybe it's on the road to deprecation or something? Just a documentation oversight? Not sure.

Comment: @PeterLyons, this is in the ECMAScript 5 spec.  Maybe they just didn't feel like documenting things that weren't node-specific.

Comment: FWIW, this appears to be documented essentially everywhere, and does not appear to be Node-specific, as of now.

Answer (score 8):

I used a two step process that I found to work:

```
var output = JSON.parse(insert_json_here);
var print_to_file = JSON.stringify(output, null, "\t")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check out [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli) - it's a command-line tool for inspecting and processing JSON data.