# Formatting JSON output in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this piece of code responsible to query a database and output the information as JSON format:

```
connectionpool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('CONNECTION error: ',err);
        res.statusCode = 503;
        res.send({
            result: 'error',
            err: err.code
        });
    } else {
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.statusCode = 500;
                res.send({
                    result: 'error',
                    err: err.code
                });
            } else {
                res.send({
                    json: rows
                });
            }
            connection.release();
        });
    }
});
```

The output is the following:

```
{"json":[{"id":39937,"transcript_alias":"AC148152.3_FGT007","expression":0,"tissue":"Leaf","conditions":"No-stress"},{"id":39941,"transcript_alias":"AC155352.2_FGT012","expression":0.217,"tissue":"Leaf","conditions":"No-stress"}]}
```

but I'd like to have this output:

```
{"json":[
    {"id":39937,
      "transcript_alias":"AC148152.3_FGT007",
      "expression":0,
      "tissue":"Leaf",
      "conditions":"No-stress"},
    {"id":39941,
     "transcript_alias":"AC155352.2_FGT012",
     "expression":0.217,
     "tissue":"Leaf",
     "conditions":"No-stress"
    }
]}
```

with break lines, making it more visible and understandable. Is that possible?

Comment: I think that this is already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693999/write-formatted-json-in-node-js

Comment: And in particular, [this answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11276104/157247) (which really should be the accepted one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into **MDN** [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> JSON.stringify(value[, replacer [, space]])

You can see that there is a third parameter to `stringify` function, called **space** wich causes the resulting string to be pretty-printed.

You can use a tab character mimics standard pretty-print appearance:

```
JSON.stringify({ first: 1, second: 2 }, null, '\t')
// returns the string:
// '{           
//     "first": 1,
//     "second": 2
// }'
```

Comment: It does not work when writing in my code `res.send(JSON.stringify(rows, null, '\t'));` instead of `res.send({json: rows});`...

Comment: The extra whitespaces means nothing different to the machine... it only matters to a human that needs to understand it. you only want to pretty print it when you actually have a person that needs to look at it

Comment: huh? I meant It is printed without tabs and nothing is formatted doing `res.send(JSON.stringify(rows, null, '\t'));`

Comment: How do you print it ?

Comment: I'm working with NodeJS, the way NodeJS send information to your browser is doing `res.send`. Again, doing `res.send(JSON.stringify(rows, null, '\t'));` it does not print anything formatted.

Comment: i dont think that `res.send` should print something , if you want to print the json you should `console.log` it formatted .