# How do I display a JSON object in a pretty format , on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript data formatting/pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130404/javascript-data-formatting-pretty-printer)

```
var theobject_string = '{...}'; // I have a json object as a string.
```

How can I display this string in a pretty way, on my webpage (html)?

I want this the elements to be indented.

Comment: Is this supposed to be pretty, as in indented nicely for someone who knows JSON to read, or pretty as in average user pretty?

Comment: Pretty for someone who knows JSON to read. This will be for myself only, for testing stuff.

Comment: I would suggest this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130404/javascript-data-formatting-pretty-printer/130479#130479 (or the accepted answer on the same post).

Comment: @Cory I agree, using Crawford's Stringify more so than the accepted answer. Maybe you should post that as an answer to this question so I can vote it up :)

Comment: After I stringify it, how do I write it to the HTML (with the indents)?  $("mydiv").html(JSON.stringify(the_object)) ?

Comment: @TIMEX: I would have something like `<div id="mydiv"><pre></pre></div>` and then `$('#mydiv pre').text(JSON.stringify(the_object));`

Answer (score 0):

This library does exactly what you're looking for: http://www.cerny-online.com/cerny.js/demos/json-pretty-printing

Comment: This is offline: http://www.cerny-online.com/cerny.js/documentation/json/TextPrettyPrinter

Comment: I guess you can take a look at the examples, and warn them about that page not working. I'm not in contact with the developers.