# Get textual (string) version of an object - displaying in the browser for debugging purposes

Tags: javascript, debugging, pretty-print

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript data formatting/pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130404/javascript-data-formatting-pretty-printer)

Would like to to translate a javascript object into a string so that I can display in the browser window.

So an object that looks like this:

```
{
   a:1,
   b:2
}
```

Would display in the browser much the same way.  The string might look something like this:

```
"{<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp a:1, <br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp b:2  <br/>
}"
```

Is there any readily available code that can do this?  Or perhaps another slick solution that doesn't involves me writing a function to process all the data myself?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130404/javascript-data-formatting-pretty-printer

Comment: @Steve - Wow, how the heck did you find that question?

Comment: I searched Google for JavaScript pretty printer, lol.

Comment: @Steve - Ohhhh, haha, I didn't realize "pretty print" was a known term.

Comment: Given that you're talking about debugging, have you tried the debugging console provided (either by default or as an add-on) by all modern browsers? Have a look into `console.dir(yourobject)`.

Comment: @nnnnnn - I use Firebug and sometimes Chrome's developer tools.  I'm not familiar with "console.dir(object)" though.  The reason I'm trying to do this is because I need to be able to look back and see objects that are associated with events that will have already come and gone in the past.

Comment: @DutrowLLC Do *not* make edits like the one that you did.  Instead, flag for moderator attention and indicate what question this is a duplicate of.

Comment: @casperOne - No problem, I see you edited it as well, did you fix it?

Comment: @DutrowLLC The banner that is at the top is auto-inserted when closed as a duplicate.  It's fixed now, but please refrain from such edits in the future.

Comment: @casperOne - Yeah man, no problem.