# my javascript is not working

Tags: javascript

my javascript is not validating

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkname()
    {
        var str1=document.form.name.value

        if (str1.length==0)
        {
            return true
        }
        else{
            alert('Please Enter Your Name!')
            return false
        }
    }

    function checkrollno()
    {
        var ph=document.form.rollno.value
        var l=ph.length

        if((ph==""||ph==null))
        {
            alert('Enter the University Roll Number')
            return false 
        }

        if(l<10)
        {
            alert('Roll no. Consists Of 10 Digits ')
            return false
        }

        return true
    }

    function checkPercent()
    {
        var name1=document.form.btech.value
        var name2=document.form.12.value

        if(name1==null||name1==""||name2==null||name2=="")
        {
            alert('Enter The Percentage')
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
</script>
```

and the form looks like

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="action.php" onSubmit="return (checkname(this) && checkrollno(this) && checkPercent(this))">
```

Comment: @PROFESSOR, you title/short description is not good, you should also use code format .. and before everything else I'd recommend you read the FAQ.

Comment: You need to edit the post to make the code more readable..also, the error output would probably be helpful.  I don't see any semicolons, which would cause syntax errors, so if you don't have those in your code, you should add them in

Comment: Semicolons in JS aren't mandatory, but causes code harder to interpret (you don't know where the statement really ends), and leads to obscure bugs.

Comment: You're passing `this` to functions which don't specify any parameters.

Comment: @KennyTM: and it is absolutely death to optimizers and minifiers to leave out the semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

```
alert('Roll no. Consists Of 10 Digits ');
return false;
```

Use `;` after each and every statement. (Not required if there is only 1 statement in a block, but still be on safe side)

Comment: Not required at all. Just best practice.

Comment: But in later stages of development, if you use minifiers/compressors, it will throw errors. And to let everything to guess for browser is not good :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You're passing 'this' into each of the functions, yet none of the functions accept/ expect an argument, so you can drop that. Add semicolons to the end of each statement. And you need to rename one of the forms on your page (or you have a typo) as you can't have a variable/ property in JavaScript that begins with a number.

```
var name2=document.form.12.value
```

Though I suppose you could try

```
var name2=document.form['12'].value;
```

but please don't. Also, where you have

```
var str1=document.form.name.value
```

.name should be the name of your form (which appears to be 'form', not 'name' though you seem to have multiple forms).

Comment: In that last example `form` is the name of the form, and shouldn't be confused with the `forms` collection. It is generally better to use `document.forms.sensibleId.elements.otherSensibleIdOrName` to avoid conflicts and for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var str1=document.forms[0].name.value
```

But for next time follow the so rules :) and try JQuery.

Comment: Avoid accessing forms by numeric index. It is the best way for things to break when the page layout changes. Using a name (which is what the OP is already doing) is a better bet.

Answer (score -1):

Change the form tag for something in the like of

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="action.php" onSubmit="ValidateAll()">
```

And create a new function:

```
function ValidateAll()
{ 
     return checkname() && checkrollno() && checkPercent()
}
```

Comment: There must a return for onSubmit -- onSubmit="return ValidateAll()"

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with these lines

```
var str1=document.form.name.value

var ph=document.form.rollno.value
```

etc.

Make sure you put a ; at the end of each line as javascript doesn't treat these as EOL.

```
var str1=document.form.name.value;

var ph=document.form.rollno.value;
```

Comment: nvi said that 20 minutes previously, and it is still wrong. JavaScript performs semi-colon insertation, it is a good way to trip yourself up, and it is best avoided, but it isn't actually a problem here.