# Closure Compiler Warning `dangerous use of the global this object`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, google-closure-compiler

Dear folks, Closure Compiler gives this warnings in Advanced Mode, underlining `{this.`

JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object at line 200 character 33
`hovers[i4].onfocus = function() {this.className += "Hovered";}`

JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object at line 201 character 32
`hovers[i4].onblur = function() {this.className = this.className.replace(/Hove...`

JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object at line 201 character 49
`hovers[i4].onblur = function() {this.className = this.className.replace(/Hove...`

JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object at line 218 character 38
`buttons[i5].onmouseover = function() {this.className += "Hovered";}`

**Q1. Whats so dangerous about this?**
**Q2. Should I change this?**
**Q3. How do I improve/solve this code?**

merci!

Comment: See also [WARNING - dangerous use of the global this object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4036949/1468366) which is an older post, with a more specific problem and some nice answers as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"this" might have different meaning in different context, so it tells you exactly that.
You can use closures instead:

Instead of

```
hovers[i4].onfocus = function() {this.className += "Hovered";}
```

have:

```
hovers[i4].onfocus = function(self) 
{
    return function() {self.className += "Hovered";}
}(hovers[i4])
```

Comment: "dangerous use of this" is not trying to warn the user regarding different meanings of "this" in different contexts.  It is a warning telling the user that, in case the compiler decides to *flatten* the namespace, any usage of "this" will point to the wrong object and will break code.  It is a warning purely having to do with optimizations performed by the compiler.

Comment: @Stephen Chung:Well, I meant the same thing. If you think I misspoke, feel free to edit my answer - English is not my first language and I might misphrase things :)

Answer (score 19):

If you know the type of the "this" variable, you can declare it with a JsDoc to stop the compiler from complaining:

```
hovers[i4].onfocus = 
/** @this {Element} */
function() {this.className += "Hovered";}
```

Caveat: this, however, assumes you know **for sure** the type of the "this" variable.  This may not be as easy as it seems.  For example:

```
foo.doSomething = function(x) { this.bar = x; }
foo.doSomething("Hello");
```

You would have known that "this" in `doSomething` refers to `foo`.  However, if you use the *Advanced Mode* of the Closure Compiler, the compiler may "flatten" the `foo` namespace and you'll end up with:

```
a = function(x) { this.b = x }
a("Hello");
```

with `foo.doSomething` being "flattened" to a single global variable `a`.  In this case, the "this" variable obviously points to the *global object* instead!  Your code will break!

Therefore, the Closure Compiler is quite adamant in warning you not to use "this" in functions that can be flattened.  You may use "this" in constructors and prototype functions without this warning though.

To resolve this, it is better to avoid using "this" by using the namespace itself:

```
foo.doSomething = function(x) { foo.bar = x; }
foo.doSomething("Hello");
```

Comment: For any functions that defines classes you should use
@constructor  is JSDoc to get rid of this warning. This is a way google recommends for this type of warning

Answer (score 8):

Just to add example of what @marcinkuzminski added comment to @stephen Chung answer

```
 /**
 * Model for ListBox
 *
 * @constructor <-- add this to remove the warning
 */
MyProject.ListBoxModel = function ( data ){

  this.data_  = data || {};   /* this gives warning */
};
```

Source : https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler