# Javascript - Correct use of 'this' in a function member of a class

Tags: javascript, annotations, google-closure-compiler

I want to use the `this` object in a function member of a class. The function can be different depending of the instance of the class. It works fine but Google Closure Compiler sends me warnings which makes me think I am not doing it properly.

Hence my question: what is the correct way of using `this` in a function that is neither a prototype nor a constructor?
If there is no, what should I do instead of trying to use `this` there?

Here is an illustration of what I am trying to do:

```
/** @constructor */
function MyAlert() {}
/** @type {string} */
MyAlert.prototype.name = "joe";
/** @type {function()} */
MyAlert.prototype.myAlert;

/** @type {MyAlert} */
var formalAlert = new MyAlert();

/** @type {MyAlert} */
var informalAlert = new MyAlert();

informalAlert.myAlert = function() {alert("Hi " + this.name);}
formalAlert.myAlert = function() {alert("Good morning Mr " + this.name);}

formalAlert.myAlert();
informalAlert.myAlert();
```

While [compiling](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#webservice) I am getting this warning and could not find a way to work around it:

```
JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object at line 11 character 57
formalAlert.myAlert = function() {alert("Good morning" + this.name);}
                                                         ^
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why wouldnt you be attaching these methods to the prototype?

Comment: I would not worry about it. What you are doing is a perfectly valid way to override behavior inherited from the prototype.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closure Compiler Warning `dangerous use of the global this object`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301373/closure-compiler-warning-dangerous-use-of-the-global-this-object)

Comment: IMO that would be better done with a class hierarchy and formal prototype overriding.

Comment: Based on the comment on the accepted answer to the above linked question, the "danger" is not in javascript itself but rather what the compiler does.  It is warning that based on that code the compiler may end up breaking it.

Comment: Every day somebody asks this same question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example:

```
formalAlert.myAlert = function() {...}
```

Creates a new static property on formalAlert which shadows (not replaces) the prototype. While still perfectly valid javascript, it is important to realize that the compiler correctly sees these as different properties.

To silence this warning, you simply need to tell the compiler the type of the 'this' object:

```
formalAlert.myAlert = /** @this {MyAlert} */ function() {...};
```

Comment: The JSDoc comment can also go on the line before.