# "dangerous use of the global this object" warning in Google Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have some code that looks like this:

```
var MyObject = function () {
  this.Prop1 = "";
  this.Prop2 = [];
  this.Prop3 = {};
  this.Prop4 = 0;
}
```

And then I later have this:

```
var SomeObject = new MyObject();
```

When I run my code through closure compiler in advanced mode, I'm getting the warning `dangerous use of the global this object` on every line where I have `this.Prop =`

What am I doing that's "dangerous" and how should I rewrite my code?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301373/closure-compiler-warning-dangerous-use-of-the-global-this-object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would *recommend* writing it like this:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.Prop1 = "";
  this.Prop2 = [];
  this.Prop3 = {};
  this.Prop4 = 0;
}
```

However, the real fix is to use the `@constructor` JSDoc notation on the line before the constructor:

```
/** @constructor */
```

Comment: ok, thanks, it was the missing @constructor that was causing the problem.

Comment: If this were a function that modified an existing object (rather than a method to be called with "new") you can use the "@this {SomeType}" annotation.

Answer (score 4):

The [Closure Compiler Error and Warning Reference](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref) provides detailed explanations for the warnings related to the dangerous use of `this`:

- JSC_UNSAFE_THIS
- JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS

The warning about using the global `this` object helps prevent accidentally calling a constructor function without the `new` keyword, which would result in the constructor properties leaking into the global scope. However, for the compiler to know which functions are intended to be constructors, the annotation `/** @constructor */` is required.