# JavaScript "this" keyword and Closure Compiler warnings

Tags: javascript, scope, google-closure-compiler

I have production code that I am now trying to minify with the Closure Compiler using the advanced option. The code uses [Paul's client side cookie libraries](http://www.paulspages.co.uk/pcp/cookielib/index.htm). The compiler generates over 30 of these warnings:

```
JSC_USED_GLOBAL_THIS: dangerous use of the global this object
```

Here are some code snippets from Paul's library (oroginal code uses named functions, not anonymous functions):

```
  var cookieObject = function (name, expires, accessPath) {
        var i, j
        this.name = name
        this.fieldSeparator = "#"
        // this.found = false
        this['found'] = false;  // don't allow Closure-Compiler to rename
        this.expires = expires
        this.accessPath = accessPath
        this.rawValue = ""
        this.fields = new Array()
        this.fieldnames = new Array() 
        if (arguments.length > 3) { // field name(s) specified
              j = 0
              for (i = 3; i < arguments.length; i++) {
                    this.fieldnames[j] = arguments[i]    
                    j++
              }
              this.fields.length = this.fieldnames.length 
        }
        this.read = ucRead            // function assignments
        this.write = ucWrite
        this.remove = ucDelete
        this.get = ucFieldGet
        this.put = ucFieldPut
        this.namepos = ucNamePos
        this.read()
  }; // cookieObject
```

The *uc* functions are typically constructed this way:

```
  var ucRead = function () {
        var search = this.name + "="
        var CookieString = document.cookie
        this.rawValue = null
        this.found = false
  }
```

I have read [How does “this” keyword work within a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133973/how-does-this-keyword-work-within-a-javascript-object-literal) as well as [Closure Compiler Warning dangerous use of the global "this" object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301373/closure-compiler-warning-dangerous-use-of-the-global-this-object) and [Scope in JavaScript](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/). However, I still don't understand what the scope of `this` is in the above code nor how I would go about rewriting this code to eliminate the compiler warnings.

Q1: Can someone clarify for me what the scope of `this` is?

Q2: Can someone provide some code snippets showing how the above can be rewritten to eliminate the compiler warnings (I assume the use of `this` has to be eliminated)?

TIA.

Comment: `this` can be quite confusing and tricky at first (and can still catch you off guard later on, when you think you get it). But [MDN provides a lot of info to get you started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: See [“dangerous use of the global this object” warning in Google Closure Compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11279087/1164465)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `this` is, essentially, unpredictable. `this` references whatever context in which the function is being called *that particular call*. For example:

```
var foo = function()//or function foo()
{
    console.log(this);
};
foo();//logs the window object
var anObj = {name:'someObject',method:foo};
anObj.method();//logs `anObj`
```

The basics are simple:

```
[[someObject]].function();//call func
    /\            ||
    ||  implicit  ||
    |______________|
```

In the irst example there was no *explicit* owner object, so JS falls back to the global object, by default. (unless when using `strict mode`). The second example, foo was used as a method, called from the object, so `this` references that object.

Now, this is all pretty easy but given that the `this` reference is determined *ad hoc*, and functions are *loosely bound* in JS (`Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments,[0]);`), There is no guarantee that *this* will *always* point to what you expect it to point to. 
ECMAScript 5 offers you the `bind` method for that, enabling you to *bind* a given context to a function object, but don't forget: there are some annoying people out there who still use outdated browsers. 
Besides, this is an *"issue"* which has been around for a long time, and people have used various workarounds. The easiest is the use of closures:

```
var MyConstructor = function()
{
    "use strict";//in strict mode, this'll throw errors when called without new keyword
    if (this === window || !this)
    {
        throw 'Omitted new keyword in older browsers, that don\'t support strict mode';
    }
    var that = this;//create closure reference to the new instance
    that.someProperty = 'Use that instead of this';
    that.especially = function()
    {
        console.log(this === that);//see later
        console.log('especially in methods, because they can be borrowed, at which point `this` could reference anything, but here: ' + that + ' Will always be what you expect');
    };
}
var foo = new MyConstructor();
foo.especially();//logs true, and 'especially in methods ...'
bar = [];
foo.especially.apply(bar,[]);//logs false, but the second log will still be the same
```

Comment: Thank you. FYI: Your suggestion to use a closure led to these questions: [Details on returning an object literal from a closure in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130014/details-on-returning-an-object-literal-from-a-closure-in-javascript)

Comment: In addition, the compiler rewrites code in unexpected ways which often change the object to which the `this` keyword refers. See http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth: thanks for the link, I guess the name says it all: if you want your code to work, use closures as much as you can :).