# Details on returning an object literal from a closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, closures, google-closure-compiler

*Background*: I want to rewrite a library (which I did not write) to avoid having the Closure Compiler generate warnings with the advanced option. Per this question [JavaScript “this” keyword and Closure Compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109358/javascript-this-keyword-and-closure-compiler-warnings) the answer was to rewrite the code using a closure. The intent is to avoid using the keyword `this` (which generates the compiler warnings).

As the library has a number of functions, I though it would be best for the new closure to return an object literal. I want to understand how this works and any possible ramifications. I therefore wrote the following (meaningless) example as a learning expercise (also here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnjGL/)):

```
  var CurrencyObject = function(Amount) {
        var money = Amount;
        return {
              "toCents": function() {
                    money *= 100;
                    return money;
              },
              "toDollars": function() {
                    money /= 100;
                    return money;
              },
              "currentValue": money  // currentValue is always value of Amount
        };
  }; // end currencyObject

  var c1 = CurrencyObject(1.99); // what's the difference if the syntax includes `new`?

  alert('cents = ' + c1.toCents() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c1.currentValue + '\ndollars = ' + c1.toDollars() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c1.currentValue);

  var c2 = CurrencyObject(2.99);

  alert('cents = ' + c2.toCents() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c2.currentValue + '\ndollars = ' + c2.toDollars() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c2.currentValue);

  alert('cents = ' + c1.toCents() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c1.currentValue + '\ndollars = ' + c1.makeDollars() + '\ncurrent money = ' + c1.currentValue);
```

**Q1**: Why isn't *currentValue* updated after the call to *toCents*? (I'm going to guess that it is because *currentValue* is a literal(?) that it is initialized when CurrencyObject is first executed. If that's the case, what's the syntax for also returning the property *currentValue*?)

**Q2**: This syntax (with `new`) `var c1 = new CurrencyObject(1.99);` does not change the code's behavior in a way that I can detect, yet I assume there is a difference. What is it?

**Q3**: When *c2* is instantiated, are copies of the functions being created or will *c1* and *c2* share the same (function) code? (If copies of the functions are being created, what changes do I make to avoid that?)

TIA

BTW: In the event someone is wondering, the symbols in the object literal are quoted to avoid having the Closure-Compiler rename them.

Comment: Just as a note - `makeDollars` isn't a valid call in your fiddle

Comment: @ianpgall Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I [branched your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnjGL/1/), and added a couple of methods that all instances will in fact share (ie: no new function objects will be created for each instance): the methods that convert the amount into Euro's or Pounds, for example. I've also omitted the `money` variable, because it's simply not necessary. To avoid having to use `this` as much as possible, I've also assigned the returned object to a variable within the closure scope, so that all methods can reference their parent object via that variable name, rather than having to rely on `this`.
Shared methods, however, will still have to use `this` occasionally, because they were declared in a *"higher"* scope, and don't have access to the `returnObject` variable, simply because it doesn't exist in their scope. Lifting the `returnObject` variable declaration is no solution in case you were wondering, because then you'll soon find out that you can't create more than 1 instance of the currency object.
Lastly, I've changed the name of the *"constructor"* to start with a lower case. Technically, your function is not a constructor any longer, and convention is that it therefore can't start with an upper-case letter... Let me know if anything I explained here, or any of my suggested changes are still unclear to you.

The `currentValue` isn't updated because you changed the `money` variable's value by doing: `money *= 100;`. This statement multiplies the `money` value *and assigns it to the same variable*. Since this is a primitive, `currentValue` has its own *copy* of this value, they're not linked in any way.
Suggestions: use `return money/100;` to keep the value of `money` constant. As it now stands calling the `toCents` method twice is the same as multiplying the original amount by 10,000. To update/set the `currentValue` on each call to whatever you want it to be, add: `this.currentValue = money*100;`, which is a little dangerous, or giving your closure access to its own literal by using a named reference (which is safer, but a bit more verbose):

```
var someClosure = function (amount)
{
    var money = amount;//redundant: you can use amount, it's preserved in this scope, too
    var me = {currentValue:amount,
              toCents: function()
              {
                  me.currentValue = money*100;//<-- use me to refer to the object itself
                  return amount/100;
              }
      };
      return me;
}
```

There is no reason to use the `new` keyword: the object that is created by this *"constructor"* is an object literal, it has only 1 prototype (`Object.prototype`, and no explicit constructor name). Adding `new` will make `this` point to a new object in the function itself, but since you're not using it, and your function returns another object, the object is never returend.

Strictly speaking: some JS engines will create new function objects for each new instance. Some modern objects optimize this, and will in fact only create 1 function object. To be on the safe side, you can wrap another closure around things, to make sure there is only 1 function, regardless of what engine runs your code:

```
var someObjectGenerator = (function()
{
    var oneOffFunction = function()
    {
        console.log('this function will only be created once');
    }
    return function(amount)
    {
        return {    foo:oneOffFunction,
                    toCents: function()
                    {
                        return amoutn/100;
                    }
                };
    };
};
```

Of course, functions that are created in a scope above the one that has the `money` or `amount` variable won't have access to that variable, so in that case you'll have to create new functions... but JS objects are *very* cheap, so don't worry about it *that* much. 
Again, most engines deal with this rather well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear though I still have some details to digest. (I'm just catching up here in NJ after not having power for over a week.)

Comment: BTW, the way you use `this` in the branched fiddled does not cause the Closure Compiler to generate warnings. (The advance option saves 53% off the original size.)

Comment: @Karl: happy to help. I think the closure compile accepts the use of `this`, because it's not used to _set_ properties, and when I use it to access a method, I make sure `this` has the method I'm after (`this.toDollars ? this.toDollars() : 1`). Hope everything is ok over there after Sandy

Comment: The `val` parameter of the shared methods will always be `undefined`. Right? So why `val = val || (this.toDollars ? this.toDollars() : 1);`. I don't understand the reason for the `||` with `val`. That is, why not just `val = (this.toDollars ? this.toDollars() : 1);`? TIA.

Comment: @Karl, I added the `val` argument in case you wanted to use the shared functions as setters, or if you (accidentally or on purpose) assign a reference to that function elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1:** You've created two variables that contains separate copies of the `Amount`.  One is in the `money` variable captured in the closure.  The other copy is in the `currentValue` property of your returned object.  Those are separate variables that have no connection to one another, other than the initial value of `currentValue` is initialized with the value of the `money` variable.

To work-around this issue, you have to settle on only have one place that you store your `currentValue` and refer to it there.  You could only use the `money` local variable in the closure, but that would require changing the `currentValue` property to be a getter function (that retrieves the `money` value) rather than a direct data property.

Or, you could get rid of the `money` closure variable and only use the `currentValue` property.  That would require you to use `this` to get that property in the `toCents` and `toDollars` methods.  In my opinion, the cleaner way to do this would the latter (using `this` to reference the object's own properties).  I have no idea why closure wouldn't want you to do that.

**Q2:** When you explicitly return an object from a constructor, then it no longer matters whether the constructor is called directly as a function or with the `new` operator.  As you have observed, both create the same result.

**Q3:** Since your functions are anonymous, each new instantiation will create a new anonymous function object.  How efficient or inefficient that is will depend upon the javascript implementation.  You could make there only be one function by declaring your functions to be local named functions and referring to that name.  Then, you could guarantee that no new function was created.