# Javascript call constructor in constructor

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I'm working with [PixiJS](http://www.pixijs.com/) but my question is very general. I created a constructor (1) and within that constructor (1) I call another constructor (2). I now need to access some methods of constructor (2) from the constructor (1) but I alway get the output 'Cannot read property 'renderer' of undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Call constructor 1 and it's method 'animate':

```
stage3 = new site3();
requestAnimationFrame(stage3.animate);
```

Constructor 1:

```
function site3() {
    this.fullstage = new fullscreenstage("intimg");

    this.snowfrontblur = new PIXI.BlurFilter();
    this.snowfrontblur.blurX = 5;
    this.snowfrontblur.blurY = 5;

    this.snowfront = SpriteFromImage("resources/img/snow.png",0,0,0.5,0.5);
    this.fullstage.stage.addChild(this.snowfront);

    this.snowfront.filters = [this.snowfrontblur];
}

site3.prototype.animate = function() {
    this.fullstage.renderer.render(this.fullstage.stage);
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
};
```

Constructor 2:

```
function fullscreenstage(cavansid){
    this.renderer = new PIXI.WebGLRenderer(ww, wh, null, true);
    document.getElementById(cavansid).appendChild(this.renderer.view);
    this.interactive = true;
    this.stage = new PIXI.Stage(0x000000, this.interactive);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face has to do with how JS binds the context to a function: it's an ad-hoc binding. The context (represented by the `this` keyword) can vary depending on how and where a function object is invoked.
In this statement:

```
requestAnimationFrame(stage3.animate);
```

You pass a reference to the `animate` function object to `requestAnimationFrame`, but in doing so, the function looses its context, hence when you call that function within `requestAnimationFrame`, the `this` keyword will not be bound to `stage3`. The easiest fix is to pass the entire object:

```
requestAnimationFrame(stage3);
//in requestAnimationFrame:
function requestAnimationFrame(instance)
{
    instance.animate();
}
```

In that case, `this.fullstage.renderer.render(this.fullstage.stage);` inside the `animate` function will resolve correctly.

An other option is to bind the context to the function in a more permanent way:

```
site3.animate.bind(site3);
```

I'll add some links to details on JS's context binding over time, starting with:

[this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15174505/1230836) make sure to check the links at the bottom

[JavaScript "this" keyword and Closure Compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109358/javascript-this-keyword-and-closure-compiler-warnings/13109520#13109520)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating an reference to the own object at the beginning of `site3()` and implementing the animate method into the constructor:

```
function site3() {
    var that = this; //creating the reference
    this.fullstage = new fullscreenstage("intimg");

    this.snowfrontblur = new PIXI.BlurFilter();
    this.snowfrontblur.blurX = 5;
    this.snowfrontblur.blurY = 5;

    this.snowfront = SpriteFromImage("resources/img/snow.png",0,0,0.5,0.5);
    this.fullstage.stage.addChild(this.snowfront);

    this.snowfront.filters = [this.snowfrontblur];

    this.animate = function(){
        that.fullstage.renderer.render(that.fullstage.stage);
        requestAnimationFrame(that.animate);    
    }
}
```

Comment: defining a method inside a constructor is a terrible idea... it defeats the whole point of constructors, really: it creates a new function object for each instance. You might as well construct an object literal in the function and return that. that would be better as omitting the `new` keyword with this function clutters the context