# Why no semicolon at the end of js expression in javascriptmvc app?

Tags: javascript, javascriptmvc

I am starting to learn javascriptmvc, and in code samples, I see code without semicolons at the end of expressions. Does this count on automatic semicolon insertion or am I missing something? Code example below:

```
$.Controller("Contacts.Controller", {
        init: function(){
            this.params = new Mxui.Data();
            $("#category .list_wrapper").mxui_data_list({
                model : Contacts.Models.Category,
                show : "//contacts/views/categoryList",
                create: "//contacts/views/categoryCreate"
            }) // <------ NO SEMICOLON

            $("#location .list_wrapper").mxui_data_list({
                model : Contacts.Models.Location,
                show : "//contacts/views/categoryList",
                create: "//contacts/views/categoryCreate"
            }) // <------ NO SEMICOLON

            $("#company .list_wrapper").mxui_data_list({
                model : Contacts.Models.Company,
                show : "//contacts/views/companyList",
                create: "//contacts/views/companyCreate"
            }) // <------ NO SEMICOLON
                            // etc...
         }
      }) // <------ NO SEMICOLON
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use semicolon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399935/why-use-semicolon)

Comment: Ditto [What are the rules for Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

Comment: Semi-colons should be used after statements, not expressions. The addition of semi-colons to the code would explicitly make the subject lines statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript can be forgiving about the lack of a semicolon in ways that other languages are not. However a semicolon is recommended where you've pointed them out.

If you run the code you've given through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/), it throws up a whole stack of warnings, including complaining about those missing semicolons.

JSLint is a tool for telling you about things in your code which may not be syntax errors but which could cause problems. It generally throws up a *lot* of errors, even for relatively well written code, but it is good for picking up things which you should fix.

I would say that those code samples are poorly written because of the missing semi-colons.

Comment: I would say the semicolons were pointed out are not at all mandatory.

Comment: @mplungjan - not mandatory, but recommended. If for no other reason than if you tried to minify that code, the lack of semicolons would cause it would break.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolons are only mandatory in inline event handlers.
MOST anywhere else, a linefeed is enough. Here is an example of where it is not enough:
[Why is a semicolon required at end of line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171651/javascript-why-is-a-semicolon-required-at-end-of-line)
And as pointed out, do not leave out semicolons if you want to minify your scripts.

Comment: A linefeed is usually _not_ enough if the next line starts with a parenthesis. (e.g., `a = b + c[newline](d + e).print()` will require a semicolon somewhere on either side of `[newline]`.)

Comment: That link sort of says that, but not succinctly. Also, I wrote my comment while you were adding the link to your original post. Chalk it up to a time warp. :)

Answer (score 0):

A lot of semicolons are optional in javascript, though recommended to avoid confusion

https://mislav.net/2010/05/semicolons/