# Why so many semicolons in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I tend to be a prolific user of semicolons in my JavaScript:

```
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
if (x==y){do something};
```

I recently noticed that I was looking at a lot of JavaScript that doesn't have semicolons following if statements. It then occurred to me that I don't even know the preferred syntax for semicolons in JS and after some googling learned (rather surprisingly) that there is no need for semicolons at all aside from splitting statements that are on one line.

So, the question...where did this habit of people using semicolons come from? Is it a remnant from some popular language that was in use at the time JavaScript came into play? Just good practice in general? Is it just me?

I'm probably going to stick with it for no other reason that it's nice when writing jQuery chains to easily spot the end.

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the answers, everyone! It looks like, to summarize things, the reason we see a lot of semicolons in JS even when not needed comes from various variables:

- older JS minimizer's would produce broken code if you did not insert semicolons
- many other languages use them, so it's a carried-over habit
- on occasion, a semicolon CAN change the logic
- some prefer to use them to make the code more human-readable

Comment: semicolons are useful. They do end the statement and at times it can actually change the next statement. It also helps with debugging and readability. Semicolons after an `if` ... never heard that one before though.

Comment: I'm interested in the slew of answers you're about to get. Just remember in the end, such things boil down to personal convention. If the language allows it, there's no *right* or *wrong*.

Comment: @James...that's what actually triggered my investigation. I do notice a lot of people that use a lot of semicolons DON'T use them after `if` statements. I always have and thought maybe I was making a serious faux pas.

Comment: Use semicolons, omitting them can (sometimes) cause very ugly bugs. (but you don't need them after code blocks)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with omitting semicolons assuming you understand the ASI rules, and the ASI rules can be reasonably summarised in only a sentence or two so all JavaScript programmers really should be familiar with them. But having said that I find it easier to put them in all the time so that I don't have to keep adjusting my style every time I switch between JavaScript, Java and C#.

Comment: [Express your opinion on semicolons in JavaScript.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/352796)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many computer languages use semicolons to denote the end of a statement. C, C++, and Java are popular examples of this.

As for why people use them despite them being optional, they improve the readability of your code. In most cases it's simply done out of habit, but occasionally you need semicolons in your code to remove possible ambiguity. It's always better safe (and consistent) than sorry.

Here is an example taken from [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

```
// define a function
var fn = function () {
    //...
} // semicolon missing at this line

// then execute some code inside a closure
(function () {
    //...
})();
```

This will be interpreted as:

```
var fn = function () {
    //...
}(function () {
    //...
})();
```

Additionally, semicolons allow Javascript to be packed/minified properly. Otherwise all the statements will be mushed together into one big mess.

Comment: oh! That's an interesting example!

Comment: If your minification software can't deal with optional semicolons it is by definition broken. There are JS minifiers that do cope.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript requires semicolons. But it does have Automatic Semi-colon Insertion.

The majority of JavaScript programmers are smarter than ASI and prefer to be explicit with their semi colons.

Comment: The statement "JavaScript requires semicolons" isn't true in any practical sense though is it? Not from the coder's point of view anyway. If I can write correct code without semicolons they're not really required.

Comment: @nnnnnn: That is subjective. And when ASI bites you, it is worthwhile knowing why.

Comment: @alex: Sure, ASI can bite you. Definitely it's good to know why. I tend to use semicolons everywhere myself. I'm just saying that because of ASI semicolons are not "required".

Comment: @nnnnnn: Depends on your point of view; from the characters that make up the code, they are not required. When the interpreter is working, they are required. I think there is probably some preprocessor that puts them in there.

Answer (score 4):

The habit comes from fear. Fear of "broken" js compressors (I've had some problems with Plone compressors with legacy js that didn't have the `var` statement for example), fear of possible broken browser implementations, the list goes on. So, why not just use `;` everywhere and avoid all of these pitfalls?

The problem with this approach (just always use semicolons without further explanation) is that you don't try to understand why are you doing it in the first place, you just do because someone said you to do it, and, IMHO, this can be harmful as well. And the broken compressors you had in the past are now fixed, and you keep inserting semicolons... breaking habits is hard. We just keep doing things because "we always did it".

> Many new JavaScript programmers are advised to just use semicolons
>   everywhere, and expect that if they do not intentionally use the
>   semicolon insertion rules, they can safely ignore the existence of
>   this entire language feature. This is not the case, because of the
>   restricted productions described above, notably the return statement.
>   When becoming aware of the restricted production issue, programmers
>   may then become overly wary of linebreaks, and avoid them even when
>   they would increase clarity. It is best to be familiar with all the
>   rules for ASI so as to be able to read any code regardless of how it
>   is written, and to write code that is as clear as it can be.

Here is a [great resource](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) about this subject and the source of the quote. A great read.

> **So which style is better?** 
>   To the extent that there is an objectively
>   “better” choice, it appears to me that the
>   minimal-semicolon/comma-first style is slightly superior, both because
>   it is fundamentally more scannable and because it encourages
>   programmers to better understand the language they use.

... and the 2nd quote from a more [optionated article](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding), against always using semicolons. A great read as well.

Answer (score 3):

Whether to use semicolons or not is largely a matter of choice. However, in javascript, unlike many other languages, not using them can lead to unexpected results. For example,

```
return
    {'foo':'bar'};
```

will, because of javascript's automatic semicolon insertion, return nothing.

Comment: And the "just insert semicolons everywhere" method doesn't help with this particular example since to, say, a Java programmer it looks like one statement with a semicolon when really it is two separate statements, one of which doesn't have the semicolon. (Note: this example returns "undefined", not "nothing". Given that JS has both "undefined" and "null" I think this is important.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to remain a debatable question as to the origin of how this this manner of coding came to be, but it could have come from the ability to differentiate between 1 and many statements within an *if* conditional, which is common in most languages. And also, people could have confused syntax with JavaScript's *object literal*

First, you have the single statement if:

```
if (someNumber == 2)
  doSomething();
else
  doSomethingElse();
```

Then, you have the multi-statement if (no semi-colon needed):

```
if (someNumber == 3) {
  doThisFirst();
  doThisSecond();
} else
  doSomethingElse();
```

This syntax could also be confused with JavaScript's *object literal*, which does need a semi-color:

```
var SomeObjectLiteral = {
  property: 2,
  doSomething: function() {
  }
};
```

Basically, the semi-colon is important in Javascript to determine where a command, or definition, ends. And Braces are just as important to determine blocks of these commands. But, you can have as many semi-colons as you want. If in doubt, use a semi-colon, but be prepared if someone calls you out for not needing one :)

Answer (score 0):

The C language uses semicolons at the end of statements, and also uses braces.

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses semicolons at the end of lines, and that's why i use them in javascript usually.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons mark the end of statements in JS, but I do not put semicolons after a close-brace, only after a statement within a brace and ALWAYS on a return statement.

In your example I dont find it necessary.

Comment: why not after close-braces? Is it just redundant?

Comment: the close brace signifies the end of the statement or closure, no need

Comment: ...or the closing of an object literal.

Comment: I don't put semicolons after the closing brace of if, for, while, try, etc. blocks. I do put them after the closing brackets of assignment statements (e.g., if assigning something equal to an object literal or to a function expression).

Answer (score 0):

you can write multiple statement within the function with help of semicolon; semicolon used to separate the statement. easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from code readability, the use of semi-colons comes into picture when you actually try to minify your code. After minification, if there are no semicolons in your code, javascript engine might fail to know which statement ends where as there will be no longer be any new lines in the code.

Comment: What's the difference (in terms of file size) whether you use semicolons or line-breaks?