# Javascript Lint claims extra semicolon is bad (after `if`)

Tags: vim, jslint

I have [Javascript Lint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/) set up to carry out syntax checking in vim, and when I have a statement such as

```
if (i > 0){
 i--;
};
```

It generates the following warning

```
test.js|160 warning| empty statement or extra semicolon
```

I thought that it is best to always end statements with semicolons (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673208/why-so-many-semicolons-in-javascript)). It's not issuing an error, but why the warning? How can I change this. I don't countless warnings when I am looking for legitimate warnings.

Comment: The warning is legitimate. I do think that you should be able to turn it off, if you like, though I can't help you with that, but it's correct.

Comment: why though, isn't it better, or at least no worse, to have semi colons after if statements?

Comment: I think it's a matter of taste. I do think it's worse, but, as I said, you're entitled to your opinion and technical means to enforce it locally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Guess it's complaining about the final semicolon after your closing brace.

```
};
```

In any programming language I have used, it is not normal to close blocks with semicolons. The block is closed by the closing brace.

There's more discussion on [JavaScript: When should I use a semicolon after curly braces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2717949/127035).

Comment: Yes, but my question is why that is a warning. It should be perfectly legal.

Comment: The reason it's a warning is {...} is a complete statement. {...} followed by a semi-colon is two complete statements, one of which is empty.

Comment: Yes, empty statement is perfectly legal. Hence warning, not error ;-)