# 2 following self-invoking functions don't work

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

Whats wrong with this code?

```
function test() {

   (function(){
      console.log('1')  
   })()

   (function(){
      console.log('2')
   })()
}

test()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VvaCX/

Comment: oh please have the habit of ending with `;` even if JavaScipt allows so. For readability and cross-platform sake?

Comment: Classic example of why you just need to add semi-colons to your code! Now don't be stubborn ;)

Comment: I can't accept in 10 min, now I can

Comment: I understand that, but this is not your first question. Anyway, just giving some info, don't worry ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the semi-colons from the end of each function call...

```
function test() {

    (function(){
        console.log('1');  
    })();

    (function(){
        console.log('2');
    })();
}

test();
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5H2u/) of the working code if you need to test it. For example, in Chrome you can right-click > inspect element > and switch to the "Console" tab

Thanks to @pimvdb for pointing out what this actually attempts to do when you do not have the semi-colons:

> It is currently trying to pass the second function as an argument to the result of the first.

Comment: +1 It is currently trying to pass the second function as an argument to the result of the first.

Comment: Finally, a clear semantic argument for the use of semicolons in JavaScript! I've been looking for this for ages!

Comment: JS's wishy-washy attitude toward semicolons can mask problems like that illustrated here. Can also work against you in the other direction, as described by Crockford on page 102 of The Good Parts.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: are you sure you looked in the right places? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript#answer-1169596

Answer (score 2):

I've just tested. You NEED your semi-colons.

This works:

```
function test() {

    (function(){
        console.log('1');
    })()

    (function(){
        console.log('2');
    })()
}

test()
```

Firebug shows the error at `console.log('1')`,