# Why does code without a semicolon still work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How come in JavaScript you can call a function without `;`?

#### Example

Let’s say testMethod is declared somewhere...

```
testMethod();

testMethod() // Without semicolon will still work.
```

Also calling a method within an element
example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="testMethod();" />
<input type="button" onclick="testMethod()" /> // Again no semicolon.
```

Comment: semi colons are required to separate statements. Since there's only a single statement in your onclick, there's an implied/invisible ; in there between the `)` and the `"`.

Comment: what about inside the <script>

Comment: same thing. if the script block ends, there's an implied ; just before the end of the block.

Comment: same deal, one statement per line, javascript can handle this distinction and will insert the `;` for you.  If you had multiple statements per line i believe you would need to insert the `;` after each statement on the same line.

Comment: so if I have 2 statements It will be an error inside <script>?

Comment: Read the comments and answers - you can have 100 lines of code with no semicolons with no errors as a result.  Personally, I insert the semicolons for clarity.

Comment: SO IN SHORT JUST USE ; END OF DISCUSSION ^_^.

Comment: @user1349313: Not at all. Be knowledgeable about where/how the ECMAScript specification requires automatic insertion, and write your code to follow the spec.

Answer (score 32):

It's a feature called "Automatic Semicolon Insertion" (or ASI).

From [Dealing with JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/6/automatic-semicolon-insertion/)

> So how are these semicolons inserted for you? By following these rules
>   (paraphrased and simplified from ECMA-262 3rd edition, 7.9.1):
>
> - When, as the program is parsed, a token (called the offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
>   1. The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator.
>   2. The offending token is }.
> - When the end of the
>     input stream of tokens is encountered and the parser is unable to parse the input token stream as a single complete program, then a semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the input stream.
> - A token is a restricted token when it is allowed by some production of the grammar, but the production is a restricted production and the token would be the first token for a terminal or nonterminal immediately following the annotation “[no LineTerminator here]” within the production.
>
> *If furthermore the restricted token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the restricted token.*
>
> ...

Comment: [An Open Letter to JavaScript Leaders Regarding Semicolons](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Answer (score 2):

Because the JavaScript engine places semicolons at the end of line if it thinks they should have been there. This often introduces bugs rather than avoiding them:

```
return
{
  user: 'foo'
}
```

The return statement above returns... nothing:

```
return;
{
  user: 'foo'
}
```

Comment: "Rarely" would be more accurate than "often" — if it were often, nobody would think ASI worked reliably.

Comment: Just my $.02, but I agree. I just found a 2 lines of code were I left off the semicolon on accident, and was curious as to *why* it was still working without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript interpreters will add semicolons for you. Omitting semicolons is a very bad idea as it can cause interpreted JavaScript code to behave differently than you'd expect due to this.

See the breaking examples [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons):

```
return
a + b;

// Returns undefined. Treated as:
//   return;
//   a + b;
```

Related:

*[Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)*

Comment: The issue in your example has nothing to do with omitting semicolons.

Comment: Bacause the COMPLETE RETURN command should be written in the same line when you go by no-semicolon. The correct is **return a+b**