# JavaScript - Replace all commas in a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, substitution

I have a string with multiple commas, and the string replace method will only change the first one:

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
mystring.replace(",","newchar", -1)
```

**Result**: `"thisnewcharis,a,test"`

The documentation indicates that the default replaces all, and that "-1" also indicates to replace all, but it is unsuccessful. Any thoughts?

Comment: What documentation? The standard - http://es5.github.com/#x15.5.4.11 - does not define a third parameter, and MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace - defines a non-standard third parameter as a string representing flags, not an integer...

Answer (score 903, accepted):

The third parameter of the [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function was never defined as a standard, so most browsers simply do not implement it. It was eventually removed and replaced with [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) (see below).

---

### Modern solution (2022)

Use [`String.prototype.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll). It is now supported in all browsers and NodeJS.

```js
var myStr = "this,is,a,test";
var newStr = myStr.replaceAll(",", "-");

console.log( newStr );  // "this-is-a-test"
```

---

##### The old way is to use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with `g` ([*global*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags_2)) flag

```js
var myStr = "this,is,a,test";
var newStr = myStr.replace(/,/g, "-");

console.log( newStr );  // "this-is-a-test"
```

###### Have issues with regular expressions?

It is important to note, that regular expressions use [special characters that need to be escaped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions). For example, if you need to escape a dot (`.`) character, you should use `/\./` literal, as in the regex syntax a dot matches any single character (except line terminators).

If you need to pass a variable as a replacement string, instead of using regex literal you may create a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object and pass a string as its first argument. The usual escape rules (preceding special characters with `\` when included in a string) will be necessary.

```js
function escapeRegex(str) {
    return str.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"); // $& means the whole matched string
}

var myStr = "this.is.a.test";
var reStr = escapeRegex(".");
var newStr = myStr.replace(new RegExp(reStr, "g"), "-");

console.log( newStr );  // "this-is-a-test"
```

Comment: Excellent answer. /g makes global search of comma and replacing it in entire string.It works this way, Am I correct??

Comment: Can you please describe in details regarding /"Seprator"/g

Comment: @MSTdev This is a typical *regular expression* with `g` flag (a.k.a. *"global search"*). The algorithm is simple: regular expression finds ALL matches (here commas) in the given string. More information about regular expressions in JavaScript you can find in [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags).

Comment: Not working in TypeScript.

Comment: What if i need to replace "\" ?

Comment: @chows2603 use `/\\/g` and it will work.

Comment: What about if I want to remove all / from my string?

Comment: @Anna nothing special, just escape it as well: `/\//g`.

Comment: Have an upvote. And a slight tweak for more elegant display if your target is text rather than data: var newStr = myStr.replace(/,/g, ' -'); [The space in front of the hyphen centers it in the 3 spaces between words which normally result from a comma's placement adjacent to a word, followed by a space and a new word.

Answer (score 184):

Just for fun:

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"  
var newchar = '|'
mystring = mystring.split(',').join(newchar);
```

Comment: This works w/o Regex, globaly, with variables and special characters (ex: '['+variable+']'). Genius.

Comment: it's a good answer, I tested the `replace` function with dots '.' but it doesn't work as expected, but you answer made it good

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova that is because in regex, the period is a special character, and you should escape it with `\.` Example: `var mystring = "this.,.is.,.a.,.test";  mystring.replace(/\./g , "|");` See [MDN RegExp - Special characters meaning in regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Special_characters_meaning_in_regular_expressions)

Comment: is it slower/faster than regex with /g?

Comment: Note a semicolon is missing from the second line above (var newchar) I tried to make an edit but stackoverflow said I couldn't...

Comment: @CSchwarz - I was about to make the edit for you but then remembered that many [JS semicolons are optional](https://news.codecademy.com/your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript) including these. Many developers very [adamantly insist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/8112776) on including them anyway. While I have no qualms about editing answers if I'm 100% sure (exception: took me 2 days to muster courage to edit one of [Atwood](//stackoverflow.com/users/1)'s answers, lol), but in this case I'll leave it as-is. You'll be [able to edit](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) at 2000 rep. 

Answer (score 52):

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
mystring.replace(/,/g, "newchar");
```

Use the global(`g`) flag

[**Simple DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/hunAx/)

Comment: not working for var mystring = "this,is.a.test"
mystring.replace(/./g, ">");  It replace the whole string

Comment: @DineshJain In regex dot (`.`) has a special meaning, it means every char, and like all other special chars, needs to be escaped with `\` if you want to use their value "literally". if you want to replace only dots you need to use  `\.`.

Comment: I added the String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
       var target = this;
       return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
      };  solves my problem @gdoron Thanks