# Javascript replace code

Tags: javascript

I use calculations on my company time sheet.

But if someone types 7,5 i get Nan with 7.5 it works.

ive added this code to assure that letters used will count as 0.

What can i add to automatic replace , with a . or simply forbid useing ,

```
function getNumber(str) {
    return isNaN(str)|| str==null?0:Number(str);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace all commas in a string javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610402/replace-all-commas-in-a-string-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNumber(str){
      var num = str.replace(/,/g,".").replace(/[^\d\.]/g, "");
      return isNaN(num) ? 0 : +num;
}
```

This function replace "," to "." and then erase everything but numbers and ".";

Comment: Thank man it works like a charm.... Did try the str.replace but never got it to work.