# How do I replaceAll character from json string using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have below json data I need to replace "=" to ":" by Javascript

```
{ "name"="John", "age"=30, "car"=null }
```

Expected output:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Replace all commas in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610402/javascript-replace-all-commas-in-a-string)

Comment: That's not a valid json string. You can play around with `replace` but it's better to fix how that json is generated. Every language has a method  to convert an object json string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = '{ "name"="John", "age"=30, "car"=null }';
str = str.replace(/=/g,":");

var json = JSON.parse(str);
```

Note, that it would convert ALL "=" to ":". If there can be symbol in name or value, different approach should be used.

--
Update "g" modifier has to be used if there is more than one "=" to replace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I am getting output :- {name: "John", age: 30, car: null}

Answer (score 0):

Use `g` flag:

```
'{ "name"="John", "age"=30, "car"=null }'.replace(/\=/g, ':')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let op = `{ "name"="John", "age"=30, "car"=null }`.replace(/=/g, ':')

console.log(op)
```