# JavaScript semicolon-less code style and minification?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to decide if it worth to go with JavaScript semicolon-less style.

If I have JavaScript code without semicolon:

```
function(){
    var first = 1
    var second = 2
    sum = 1 + 2
    return sum
}
```

it will work in browser and [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js).

But will minified (by Uglify or [Closure Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Closure_Tools#Closure_Compiler)) code work in browser and Node.js?

I've read the article *[Semicolons in JavaScript are optional](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/)*. it says that it should work.

Comment: The minification should add semicolons where needed, if just to replace the linebreaks.

Comment: Might depend on how the minifiers work.

Comment: @Pointy, +1, get off his `;` key! (because pointy things are often sharp)

Comment: Using no semicolons in a language that has pretty much the syntax of every single curly-braces-and-semicolons language does *not* make the code look cleaner! While I hate the CoffeeScript syntax it *might* be something worth a look for you...

Comment: Here is an interesting thread on the subject (including crockford getting upset): https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057

Comment: I'm with @ThiefMaster: dislike coffeescript syntax. The only people I can imagine thinking the code looks cleaner without semicolons are BASIC and COBOL developers (with a name like `WHITECOLOR`, I wouldn't be at all surprised if I'm right about your background ;p)

Comment: @Chad ha ha well I wouldn't hurt anybody

Comment: I'm going to ask ECMA to make the `;` a requirement at the end of each statement, as it should have been from day one

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem it probably will break the web yeah =)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: at first, very likely. But that might show some people how important the language is, and may encourage some people to learn a bit more about the most misunderstood language

Comment: There is nothing wrong with not using semicolons. I would prefer ECMA not make it a requirement. (Which they haven't since this post)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm personally a pro-semicolon sort of guy, but there is a compelling argument for the alternative, which is frequently not [given a fair voice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript). As with all coding style arguments this will be a never-ending debate with no reasonable conclusion. Do what you and your team feel more comfortable with.

If you do go for a frugal semicolon approach, make sure you and your team properly understand the [automatic semicolon insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) (ASI) and statement termination rules. That is definitely a good thing to understand whatever your decision.

With respect to minification: If you don't want to risk the potential headache of a minifier bug and the associated burden of reporting it and fixing it (or waiting for a fix) because it's not doing ASI properly, then don't rely on ASI.

- Isaacs ([Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) maintainer, and therefore minification agnostic for the purposes of this question) [on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)
- He recommends this excellent [impartial analysis of the ASI rules](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Answer (score 5):

Despite that semicolons in JavaScript are optional, there's strong advice against not using semicolons:

- It makes your code vulnerable for bugs <del>resulting from removing whitespace (used in minification):</del> Try this:

  var a = 1; var b = 7; var sum = a+b
  (a + b)

<del>it minifies to `var a=1,b=7,sum=a+b(a+b);`,</del> which will result in the error `number is not a function`. There are also [other cases](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/semicolons) and [this case](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/16/beware-of-javascript-semicolon-insertion/).

**Update**: This bug wasn't resulting from minification, however, the next one is:

- It makes your code vulnerable for bugs resulting from minification: Try:

  ```
    var isTrue = true

    function doSomething() { return 'yeah' }

    function doSomethingElse() { return 'yes, dear' }

    doSomething()

    !isTrue && doSomethingElse()
  ```

  minifies to:

  ```
    var isTrue=true;function doSomething(){return "yeah"}function doSomethingElse(){return "yes, dear"}doSomething()!isTrue&&doSomethingElse();
  ```

  which results in:

  ```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token !
  ```
- It makes your code less readable and maintainable in terms of convenience: Using the semicolon has been rightfully established as good practice, and a trained JavaScript developer will be puzzled by code trying to evade the convention.

Another thing is, you have to ask yourself: What do you really gain omitting the semicolon?

- Clean Code? If you want JavaScript to not look like JavaScript, try [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript). But there are [some misguided notions](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/), which believe that pitfalls like the one mentioned above are cleared by «Easy solution: when a line starts with parenthesis, prepend a semicolon to it.». How is this clean code, and how does that help anyone reading your code?

Bottom Line: With minification, I would definitely try to use conventions of [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint). I've seen some people finally linting their JavaScript code after hours of trying to fix a bug not happening in unminified, but in minified code. Don't put yourself into this misery; semicolons may be ugly at first sight, but they keep the bugs out.

Comment: Thanks, your opinion was very helpful to me.

Comment: `var a = 1; var b = 7; var sum = a+b (a + b)` is already invalid, how should this prove your point?

Comment: @FelixKling True, I got lost there. Corrected it and included an argument proving my point.

Comment: If your minifier doesn't add semicolons before minification, I think it sucks.
I puke when I see code with semicolons. The code gets so much easier to read without them.
In any case I would write the code finnished without semicolons, and then add them before minification.

Answer (score 3):

The compilers and minifiers are probably intelligent enough to add the semicolons if needed (and if it helps the minifying process).

However! A semicolon tells the interpreter that this is the end of a statement. If it is missing, it has to look at the beginning of the next line to find out if it makes sense for the statement to continue. Then it will decide, if the next line is a new statement (i.e. a semicolon was missing) or if it's in fact the continuation of the statement from the previous line.

Without semicolons, you're slowing things down! Not to mention that this could introduce some obscure errors when the interpreter, executing the algorithm I described, decides wrong!

Comment: It seems that the only ambiguous situation is when next statement tarts with brace "(".

Comment: @WHITECOLOR The interpreter still has to look at the next line to decide that. It's worth benchamrking maybe, but doing so for every line will slow things down.

Comment: The code is compiled before run anyway, I don't think it makes any difference.
A benchmark would be cool tho. However I for sure can tell the extra load on my brain seeing all the semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it. [Semicolon insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) is a very dangerous thing. The size gain is not worth the added risk.

Douglas Crockford will not like you if you do it :) *[JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook)*

Comment: I've read this http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: :-D From what I've heard, Douglas Crockford will never like you ;) (If you don't code exactly as him)

Comment: @WHITECOLOR: While everything in that article is true, I would still advice against it. Every peice of example code you read will have semi-colons, so there's that. And also problems related to auto-inserted semi-colons can be tricky to debug.

Comment: This answer has absolutely no reasoning for its answer: -1 . Please give reasons for your opinion and justify your conclusion

Comment: semi-colons is a good thing you must not forget when you are a programmer.Except some programming languages, they don't use that, I advise you should use semi-colons to help your code clear.

Answer (score -2):

IMHO, do not do that. You don't really gain that much and semicolon is AFAIK placed there automatically, and it can be put in a place where it will produce weird bugs.