# .removeClass not functioning within .replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass, replacewith

I'm trying to make a button that will hide a specific  -- and then replace it with another hidden . However, when I test the code, everything fires correctly except for the .removeClass which contains the "display: none."

Here is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var webform = document.getElementById('block-webform-client-block-18');
        var unmarriedbutton = document.getElementById('unmarried');
        var buyingblock = document.getElementById('block-block-10');

        $(unmarriedbutton).click(function () {
            $(buyingblock).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $(this).replaceWith(function () {
                    $(webform).removeClass('hiddenbox')
                });
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The CSS on 'hiddenbox' is nothing more than "display: none.'

There is a  with the id of unmarried, which when clicked fades out a div and replaces it with a hidden div that removes the class to reveal it. However, the last part doesn't fire -- everything else does and functions properly. When I look at in the console too, it shows no errors.

Can someone please tell me where the error is? Thanks!

Edit: I may be using the wrong function to replace the div with, so here's the site: http://drjohncurtis.com/happily-un-married. If you click the "download the book" button, the the div disappears and is replaced correctly with the div#block-webform-client-block-18. However, it remains hidden.

Comment: Just out of curiosity..does it work if you add a `;` after that line?

Comment: @AlexW why would you suspect that?

Comment: @iliacholy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: @AlexW it does not. I have made the change on the link that I added on the edit and the problem still persists.

Comment: see my edit OP, get your jquery object straight

Comment: @AlexW the only time semicolon insertion would mess up a return is if you tried to do something like [this](http://pastebin.com/K3LDU47y)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

NB, use jquery !

```
    var webform = $('#block-webform-client-block-18');
    var unmarriedbutton = $('#unmarried');
    var buyingblock =$('#block-block-10');
    unmarriedbutton.click(function () {
        buyingblock.fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $(this).replaceWith( webform.removeClass('hiddenbox'));

        });
    });
```

Was too fast, i believe it's the way you select your object (getelementbyid) then you create a jquery object from it... -> use jquery API

Comment: `replaceWith()` doesn't do anything if you pass it a function and don't return anything from the function.

Comment: I used this exactly and the entire document failed. It wouldn't recognize any of the selectors.

Comment: u of unmarried was missing... @Darthfuzzy

Comment: @mikakun There was no console error, but the button wouldn't initiate the first step. In other words, with that solution, clicking the button didn't do anything.

Comment: @mikakun That did it! I'd upvote it but I don't have 15 rep to do it D: So thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The function you pass to replaceWith has to return the content you want to replace it with.  You have to actually return the content.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but you could use this if the goal is to replace it with the webform object:

```
$(this).replaceWith(function () {
       return($(webform).removeClass('hiddenbox'));
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong function then, however here is the actual site: http://drjohncurtis.com/happily-un-married. If you click the "DOWNLOAD THE BOOK!" it should return a with the div#block-webform-client-block-18 and it does, it just remains hidden (and that's after I used your solution).

Comment: I made the change on the site with the return and it still does not work -- it still remains empty.

Comment: it is `$(document.getElementById('block-webform-client-block-18')` that's creating the bug

Comment: @mikakun I don't think so.

Comment: It's not that creating the bug. I changed the var webform like you suggested and the the first function failed.