# Script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$('img').click(function(){
    var getTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
    alert(getTitle)
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/chair-228x300.jpg" alt="alt" width="228" height="300" class="size-medium wp-image-92" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

This will basically display the alt attribute of the image in a popup once clicked but it seems not working. What am I missing? Please help.

Comment: you're missing ; in alert(getTitle)

Comment: How should I know? Or am I missing some tags? Im still new in scripts.

Comment: "Script not working" yeaaaaaaaaaaaah

Comment: @IswantoSan: No, it is optional.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: @IswantoSan semi-colons are optional. it's just a bad practice to omit them.

Comment: This trips a lot of people up. Even so, you should consider editing your question to have a more descriptive title than "Script not working," and then maybe people will stop downvoting you as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DOM` is not ready to be manipulated/accessed when your code executes. Use the `document.ready` shortcut:

```
$(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        var getTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
        alert(getTitle)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jQuery in a [document ready call](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function(){
        var getTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
        alert(getTitle);
    });
});
```

You're executing your code before the actual elements you want to apply it to have been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the DOM to fully load.

```
   $(function() {
         // your code goes here
    });
```

**example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y6sL/**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(function(){
   $('img').on('click', function(){
    var getTitle = $(this).attr('alt');
    alert(getTitle)
   });
});
```

Comment: @Boy Pasmo is the code working for you?