# Best syntax for inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Is there any difference between

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Link</a>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Function()" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Button" />
```

and

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Function();" OnClick="btn_Click" Text="Button" />
```

?

(The `;` after the JavaScript is the difference - does this have any effect on any specific browsers or anything?)

Comment: Belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You should avoid words like "best" in your title.  Some people will jump the gun and close the question as "opinion based".  The question I think is fine but the title makes it seem off topic.

Comment: In your simple examples, there's no difference. It can become "necessary" in some/several scenarios though. Here's some info on semicolons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript ||| http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: both void(0) and "return Function()" do absolutely nothing! a semi is the least of the concerns here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion, so there is no significant difference when you're simply setting an inline event handler with a one-liner.

---

That said, you shouldn't be adding your event handlers to inline attributes. Instead, you should keep your HTML in `.html` files, your CSS in `.css` files and your JS in `.js` files. Bind events using `addEventListener` (or [jQuery's `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on)), and you'll be able to change your bound events in one place, rather than having to search through every HTML file where you might have added an `[onclick]` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

No, the `;` is if you want to execute multiple commands one after another.

Example:

```
onclick="alert('hello world'); alert('hello world2')"
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/menelaosbgr/UggHq/

---

Edit:

As zzzzBov answered, javascript has automatic semicolon insertion.

[What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)