# Aptana "Missing semicolon" warning

Tags: javascript, aptana, aptana3

Last week I updated Aptana studio to last version (Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.2.201308081805). And now shows me warnings everywhere for missing semicolons in my JS files. I know these are optional in JS, and almost useless in some cases like this, which gives me a "missing semicolon" warning:

```
var LogLevels = {
    debug   : 4,
    info    : 3,
    warning : 2,
    error   : 1,
    none    : 0
}
```

So, my question is: is there a method to remove just this warning, and just for Javascript in Aptana?

Comment: I would recommend always using the semi-colon when appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: I think i'll do it this way from now, but I have many files with many warnings that bother me.

Comment: In my case, I have a single 10'000 (ten thousand) character long line with compacted javascript.  I don't want to add the semicolons where "recommended".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend always using semicolons as good practice as Kevin has said in his comment, but to answer your question.

I do not know of a way to ignore semicolon errors but you can disable javascript validation by going to:

**Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation**

Then untick Javascript Syntax Validator

Comment: Thanks to you, I found in my version that there is a special option there, that lets you choose the error level of missing semicolons, which can be "ignore". So I do not need to disable ALL javascript validation. Thanks :)