# Javascript in php not working

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I'm trying to make the page go back when the user presses the OK button on the alert box. The alert box appears but it doesn't go back to the previous page

Would i have to use a confirm window because i don't want to provide the cancel option, i just want a window to appear so the user has to click OK and it goes back to the previous page

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("Invalid please try again.")';
print 'history.back();';
print '</script>';
```

Just to provide  a little more information I'm doing this after OR

```
$link =mysqli_connect(*sensitive info*) OR  print '<script type="text/javascript">';
    print 'alert("Invalid please try again.")';
    print 'history.back();';
    print '</script>'; 
exit();
```

Comment: Is you JS code rendered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, You have missed to add `;`

```
 print '<script type="text/javascript">';
 print 'alert("Invalid please try again.");';
                                 .........^
 print 'history.back();';
 print '</script>';
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, the message comes up but it doesn't go back

Comment: is semicolon important in js? I think it isn't

Comment: @ Farnabaz Yes, You need to use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: @Farnabaz — There are times when the semi-colon can be omitted, doing so is considered bad practise, and this isn't one of them anyway.

Comment: @KrishR i change code to this and it works `print 'alert("Invalid please try again.")'."\n";`

Comment: This fixed it thanks to Krish R and Farnabaz but when the password is correct it still does this :/

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a semicolon ; after alert().

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("Invalid please try again.");';
print 'history.back();';
print '</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the ';' after your alert

```
print '<script type="text/javascript">';
print 'alert("Invalid please try again.");';
print 'history.back();';
print '</script>';
```

To find our errors in code you can use websites such as http://www.jslint.com/ to catch these errors easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
echo "alert(\"Invalid please try again.\")"; 
echo "window.location= \"/*Write ur page Link Here*/\""; 
echo "</script>";
```

Hope above code will work for you. and yeah  ";" is missing after your alert line.