# DOM changing in getJSON callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to fetch some data from youtube api and display the same on my webpage.

But for some reason, The DOM which I am changing inside the getJSON's callback does not change. In the console, when I print $el, I can see the html code in the variable. But it doesn't show up on the page nor in the view source (elements) tab.

I can't add Classes, remove Classes, or any DOM operation inside it. I'm curious about this because I have used the same thing elsewhere and it worked.

If after the page loads, I do the same thing by running this function in command line, it works perfectly.

Here is the code I am trying to use :

```
get_ytube = function(els){
    var $els = $(els)
    $.each($els, function(i, v) {
        var $v = $(v)
        var id = $v.data("link-id")

        var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id + "?v=2&alt=jsonc"

        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            var $el = $v

            $("<h5 class='title'>" + json.data.title + "</h5>" + 
                "<p class='desc'>" + json.data.description + "</p>").appendTo($el)
            console.log($el[0])
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to execute it after the window has been loaded?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // put your code here
});
```

Actually looking closer at this it looks like you're just missing a bunch of semicolons so javascript is interpreting your code incorrectly.  This post explains why [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080).

I added them and tried it myself and it works for me.  Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/gx3Us/.

```
var get_ytube = function(els) {
    var $els = $(els);
    $.each($els, function(i, v) {        
        var $v = $(v);
        var id = $v.data("link-id");
        var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + id + "?v=2&alt=jsonc";
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
            var $el = $v;
            $("<h5 class='title'>" + json.data.title + "</h5>" + "<p class='desc'>" + json.data.description + "</p>").appendTo($el);
            console.log($el[0]);
        });
});
```

}

Comment: I've tried it with $( document ).ready() and $( window ).bind( 'load' , function() {} )