# Why error occured when remove some lines of code?

Tags: javascript, html

The following code is working as expected

```js
obj = {
   go: function() { alert(this) }
}
obj.go(); // object
(obj.go)(); // object 
(a = obj.go)(); // window
(0 || obj.go)(); // window
```

but why error occurred when I comment the beginning two lines?

```js
obj = {
   go: function() { alert(this) }
}
//obj.go(); // commented this line
//(obj.go)(); // commented this line
(a = obj.go)(); // window
(0 || obj.go)(); // window
```

I didn't change any of the code above, just comment two lines which are separate from others, then the browser gives me error information? Could anyone please clarify that for me? many thanks.

Comment: works fine in my GC Console

Comment: "why error occurred" — **What** error?!

Comment: @Amit Joki, I accidentally add ; after the function definition, if I remove the ; it doesn't work again...

Comment: ReferenceError: obj is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `(` immediately after the `}` so you are trying to call the result of evaluating the block as if it was a function.

Before you do that, however,  you are trying to evaluate `a = obj.go` so it can be passed as an argument.

Since `obj` hasn't been defined yet (because the result of calling the "function" hasn't been passed to `obj`), it throws an error.

Answer (score 3):

Without a semicolon, your second sample is parsed as

```
obj = { ... }(...)();
```

Since the object is not a function, you get an error when you try to call it.

Semicolons in Javascript are optional, and your first sample is invalid syntax without a semicolon, so it implicitly inserts a semicolon.

Comment: "Since the object is not a function, you get an error when you try to call it." — That would happen, but there is another error that occurs before the code gets that far.

Comment: @SLaks, does that mean I need to add ; on every expression manually?

Comment: @bean That is a somewhat contentious issue.  According to [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/18192), Stackoverflow users tend to say yes.  You can go a step further and use a linting tool (most popular would be [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com) and [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com)) to detect this kind of thing.