# Should I add a ; after putting a function into a variable?

Tags: javascript

Should I add a **;** after putting a function into a variable?
is this code right?

```
pj.RemoveProjectTask = function (e, scope) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.remove();
};

pj.ToggleProjectTask = function (e, scope) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.toggle();
};
```

or this code:

```
pj.RemoveProjectTask = function (e, scope) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.remove();
}

pj.ToggleProjectTask = function (e, scope) {
    e.preventDefault();
    scope.toggle();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a semicolon to guard against this edge case:

```
var foo = function(){
  // your code here
}

(x=42);
```

In this case JavaScript actually invokes the function and passes in 42 as an argument, and sets `foo` to the return value of the function.

This has bitten me in the past when a build process concatenates and minifies multiple JavaScript files together, and one file ends with a function assignment like `var foo = function(){ ... }` without a semicolon, and the next file starts with closure-based code like `(function(){ ... })(window);`

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, adding a semicolon after each valid (function call, variable modification, etc) line is optional unless you want to have multiple instructions on the same line, in which case the semicolon is required:

```
function something()
{
    do_a_thing(); do_another_thing(); ...
}
```

But this could be written just as easily like so:

```
function something();
{
    do_a_thing() // Can opt not to have a semicolon
    do_another_thing(); // Can opt to have a semicolon
}
```

In most cases, it is up to you and your preferred style

Comment: are you kidding? it's **optional**?

Comment: @Mohamadshiralizadeh It's called Automatic Semicolon Insertion, and it is one of the horrible features of Javascript [that can get you in trouble if you rely on it](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#core.semicolon). Best to always explicitly add them.

Comment: Not at the end of each line. In fact, putting it after each line in your own code would result in syntax error: `function something(); {; do_a_thing(); do_another_thing(); };` is not grammatical.

Comment: @Amadan: Good point. Let me fix that...

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is optional in javascript function...anyway if add in the sense it wont create any problems.See the standard code convention
http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Answer (score 0):

`;` is optional in javascript but if you are going to follow `jslint` or `jshint` standards you should put `;` at the end of each statement.

Comment: Not at the end of each line. At the end of each *statement*. And even that is not correct, because, e.g., standalone `function foo() { ... }` is a complete statement that does not need a semicolon.