# javascript how to count amount of fizz, buzz and fiszbuzz

Tags: javascript, html, fizzbuzz

How do I count the amount of fizz, buzz and fizzbuzz? I'm not sure how to do it!!

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  var FizsBuzzOutput = ''
  var FizzCount = (i++)
  var BuzzCount = 
  var FizsBuzzCount = 

  //Loop through numbers from 1 tp 100
  //Write them oput to the screen

  for ( var i=1; i < 100; i++ ) {

   // document.write("<br />");

   //If the number is divisable by 3 then instead of writing the number, write "Fizz"

   // $( "body" ).append(  );
   

   if (i % 15 == 0){
    // document.write("FizsBuzz, ")
    FizsBuzzOutput += "FizsBuzz, "
   }

   else if ( i % 3 == 0 ){
    //document.write("Fizz, ")
    FizsBuzzOutput += "Fizz, "
   }

   
   else if (i % 5 == 0){
    //document.write("Buzz, ")
    FizsBuzzOutput += "Buzz, "
   }

   

   else {
    //document.write(i + ', ')
    FizsBuzzOutput += i + ', '
   }

  }

  document.write( FizsBuzzOutput )

  </script>

 </head>
 <body> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare the variables properly.
You should use semicolons. This shoudld be an interesting reading: [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

If you are starting to use/learn javascript eloquent javascript might help you: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Something like this should work:

```
    var FizsBuzzOutput = '';
    var fizz = 0;
    var buzz = 0;
    var fizzbuzz=0;



    for ( var i=1; i < 100; i++ ) {


        if (i % 15 == 0){
            fizzbuzz+=1;                
            FizsBuzzOutput += "FizsBuzz, ";
        }

        else if ( i % 3 == 0 ){
            fizz+=1;
            FizsBuzzOutput += "Fizz, ";
        }


        else if (i % 5 == 0){
            buzz+=1;
            FizsBuzzOutput += "Buzz, "
        }       
        else {

            FizsBuzzOutput += i + ', ';
        }
        console.log(FizsBuzzOutput);
    }
 console.log('fizz count= '+ fizz);
 console.log('buzz count= '+ buzz);
 console.log('fizzbuzz count= '+ fizzbuzz);
```

Here is a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7caLpjd/1/