# Is always putting a semicolon after an end curly-brace a bad idea?

Tags: javascript

I sometimes like to work quickly, so I set a macro in my editor to always add a semicolon after an end curly-brace, even when not necessarily needed. For example:

```
var test=function(){
    //I realize the semicolon after the curly-brace below is required
};

function test(){
    //But is it safe to have on where it isn't required, like below?
};
```

As in, will it create errors, slow down the site, or create compatibility issues? I will remove these additional semicolons when I am finished developing the product, but for now, is it OK?

Comment: No, none of those things will happen.

Comment: It does not cause any errors on a program level. Its just better for consistency and it looks better. Also there is no difference between those two.

Comment: don't ALWAYS do it: `var a={a:1}, b=[1,2];`

Comment: Or just never declare more than one variable on a single. It's really your choice, but it is a choice to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a program level, it makes no difference to have this:

```
function() {

};
```

Or this:

```
function() {

}
```

I do recommend that you pick one way to do it and stick with it for the purpose of consistency.

You should also read through this post:
[Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)
A lot of good points on this subject are made there.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit of a noob here, so I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something horribly bad.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are cases where adding a semicolon after an ending curly bracket can cause issues, e.g.:

```
let data = {
  item1: [],
  item2: {}; // This semicolon is a syntax error
};
```