# Practicing 2D Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a script that will generate a square room within a larger map. The code looks like this:

```
var mapSize = 10;
var map = [];
for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
    map[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
        map[x][y] = 0
        };
    };
//Make square room within map
var roomSize = 3;
var roomType = "Kitchen"
var paintRoom = function(mapX, mapY) {
    for (var j = 0; j < roomSize; j++) {
      map[mapX + j][mapY] = roomType;
      map[mapX][mapY + j] = roomType;
    };
};
paintRoom(3, 4);
console.log(map);
```

The result that I want is this:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

But instead I end up with this:

```
[
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", "Kitchen", "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, "Kitchen", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

What am I missing here? I'm just starting out, and would like to figure out as much as possible on my own, so if anyone could give me a hint instead of answering outright, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Rows are Ys, cols Xs.

Comment: @janje They can be Brian and Hilary - it doesn't really matter for the sake of example code.

Comment: That is true, but I'm not sure renaming them would solve the problem. Or would it?

Comment: you do not need `;` after a block `{ ... }`.

Comment: @LucienLachance no, it wouldn't.  I've given an answer below and explained what was wrong.

Comment: What is it with the innocuous comments today?  @NinaScholz that's actually really good practice and it will never be a problem, whereas leaving them out could very easily be.

Comment: @LucienLachance Perhaps, but naming things counter-intuitively can't be a good practice.

Comment: @Archer, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) states "*Note that the block statement does not end with a semicolon.*", but inserting does not harm;;;;;;;; :)

Comment: @NinaScholz You can put a million semi-colons on a line if you want.  It's a terminator and has NO side-effects.  That link you gave shows a page that says a particular example _"does not end with a semicolon"_, but in no way suggests that it SHOULD not.  Try this instead... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doing what you've asked, if you follow the code carefully.  It just needs an extra loop.  Since what you're doing is 2 dimensional then you'll need 2 loops as well...

```
var paintRoom = function(mapX, mapY) {
    for (var x = 0; x < roomSize; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < roomSize; y++) {
            map[mapX + x][mapY + y] = roomType;
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you a missing 1 loop:

```
var mapSize = 10;
var map = [];
for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++) {
    map[x] = [];
    for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++) {
        map[x][y] = 0
        };
    };
//Make square room within map
var roomSize = 3;
var roomType = "Kitchen"
var paintRoom = function(mapX, mapY) {
    for (var j = 0; j < roomSize; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < roomSize; k++) {
         map[mapX + j][mapY + k] = roomType;
      }
    };
};
paintRoom(3, 4);
console.log(map);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfnpesmd/