# Javascript self invoking function not working in angular ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, self-invoking-function

The code inside the controller is:

```
(function(){
    $scope.show();
    profile.friend_requests_to_me_service(loggedInUser.id).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.friend_requests_to_me = data.data.friend_request_to_me;
        $scope.friends = data.data.people_you_may_know;
        $scope.hide();
    });   
})();
```

As you can see this function is calling the service profile and a method of that service.The problem is that this invoking function is not working.The error is given:
`TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function`.In plunker i have checked a trivial self invoking function.Here is the link:http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4582/.
This trivial self invoking function is working.But I cant understand why my actual app self invoking function is not working.Thank you for your time.

The present working version(non self invoking) is:
     `$scope.friendship_requests_to_me_function = function(){
        $scope.show();
           profile.friend_requests_to_me_service(loggedInUser.id).then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.friend_requests_to_me = data.data.friend_request_to_me;
            $scope.friends = data.data.people_you_may_know;
            $scope.hide();
        });

    }
    $scope.friendship_requests_to_me_function();`

Comment: With uglify? Try add a ";' before your self invoking function.

Comment: @YinGang yes it is working

Comment: Didnt understand what was the problem?No where in the documentation is given this syntax.@YinGang if you can provide me an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably one of your js statement is missing a ';' at the end.

**Try add a ';' before your self invoking function**.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

> We end up passing the second function as an argument to the first function and then trying to call the result of the first function call as a function. The second function will fail with a "... is not a function" error at runtime.