# querySelector in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a  way to make TypeScript not throw the error `'TS2339: property value does not exist on type Element'` for code like this:

```
myRow.querySelector('.my-class').value = myVal
```

Casting as < HTMLInputElement > Causes the code to break entirely.

Typescript seems to not handle things involving the DOM well in general, unless I'm missing something; ie it chooses specific over general for functions that could return any element.

Comment: This: `(myRow.querySelector('.myClass') as HTMLInputElement).value = myVal` doesn't work?

Comment: Correct. That yields the error: '2349: Cannot invoke an express whose type lacks a call signature.'

Comment: What is `myRow`?

Comment: For the purpose of this question, any HTML element. The result of querySelector is an HTMLInputElement.

Comment: Can you post a link to a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that demonstrates this scenario?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h8kuwb2g/   To clarify, this seems to arise from the fact that value is a property of HTMLInputElement, but not HTMLElement. attributes like 'id' don't raise this error.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The [querySelector](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L17903) method returns `Element | null`.
If you're not using `strictNullChecks` then [Element](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L7728), and it doesn't have the `value` member.

And so casting it to `HTMLInputElement` as I wrote in my comment works:

```
let myRow = document.getElementById('my-row');
(myRow.querySelector('.myClass') as HTMLInputElement).value = " a vaule";
```

The error you are receiving is a result of forgetting the semicolon at the end of the first line, what happens is that the compiler thinks that you're trying to do this:

```
document.getElementById('my-row')(myRow.querySelector('.myClass') as HTMLInputElement)
```

Don't forget to end lines with semicolons.

---

#### Edit

The `querySelector` method is generic so you can also do:

```
document.getElementById('my-row').querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.myClass').value
```

And in case of `strictNullChecks` if you're sure the element is there you can use the [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
document.getElementById('my-row')!.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.myClass')!.value
```

Comment: Thanks; that works. Nailed it on the semicolon. Do you know why that's required?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: Per this page: https://github.com/rse/es6-features, "Both ECMAScript 6 and all tools (including compressors) perfectly support automatic semicolon inference/insertion nowadays. As a consequence, ECMAScript 6 coders nowadays can get rid of nearly all semicolons and remove clutter from their source code." Ie, it's weird to require a semicolon in this specific case.

Comment: "...get rid of **nearly all** semicolons". In your case it makes a difference

Comment: Do I always have to cast when I use this element? What if I'm quite sure that this element exists on my page. Can I already specify its type when I first declare and query it.

Comment: document.getElementById('my-row')!.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('.myClass')!.value -> this still gives me error "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments." while building

Comment: Why does the querySelector return element? The MDN documentation says that it returns an HTMLElement.

Comment: I don't like this answer. In your second example, what if it found a `div` element? Your subsequent types would be wrong.

Comment: @dwjohnston mdn is nice and all, but still the typescript definitions state that `document.querySelector` returns `Element | null`, that won't change based on you liking my answer or not.  also, there is no "finding of an element" in typescript. ts is for complication time only. the compiler has no way of knowing what will be found at runtime. therefor the the `querySelector` is generic and it's up to the developer to know what is going to be there at runtime. you should read/understand more before posting wrong statements

Comment: @NitzanTomer re: 'The compiler has no idea what will be returned at runtime' - I agree, but your answer should have that caveat with the second suggestion. The real safe solution would be that make some kind of assertions about the found element to check that it really is an HTMLInputElement, before casting it as such.

Comment: @dwjohnston you're wrong again. i mean, you can have assertions in you code, but why would you want to? do you make that assertion in js when you do `const input = document.getElementById("someInputElementId")` that `input` is indeed of the right type or do you trust that your html code is as you wrote it? the whole idea of the generic constraint is to give the developer the ability to tell the compiler that he knows better in this case. the op has mentioned that his element is `HTMLInputElement`, so that's what i used.

Comment: the clue  as HTMLInputElement helped me to fix my issue. thanks

Comment: @NitzanTomer you said "trust that your html code", but who says it is "your" html code? What if a team member changes it? What if you change it, but forget to update your TS code? What if a `querySelectorAll` can actually return different elements? What if you code a web scraper and you really cannot know the HTML code? In all those cases you would waste time to find the error, that could be avoided by coding "really" type safe.

Comment: I simply can't get through that thing of leaving semicolons. Maybe it's because I come from C++, where your freedom ranges between the rules.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers here did not help.
I found elsewhere and via trial and error that

1. querySelector is an `HTMLElement`
2. querySelectorAll is an array of them `HTMLElement[]`

```
sections: HTMLElement[] = [];

this.sections = someElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('li') as HTMLElement[];
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```
const myClass: HTMLInputElement | null = document.querySelector(".my-class") as HTMLInputElement;

if (myClass) {
    myClass.value = myVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//  define
export const $ = <T>(selector, scope = document): T =>
  scope.querySelector(selector);


//  use
const $account: HTMLInputElement = $("#login-account");

// example tips for  .value
const account = $account.value
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 