# Typescript: Type 'null' is not assignable to type error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I am getting an error while converting the following code to typescript.

```
const element = document.querySelector('#launcher');
if (element && element.style && element.style.display) {
    element.style.display = '';
}
```

> error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.

and when I assign required values for same as like below

```
const element: { style: any } = document.querySelector('#launcher');
```

then the error is on the element and that is

> error TS2322: Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type '{ style: any; }'.
>     Type 'null' is not assignable to type '{ style: any; }'.

Comment: try using `var or let` instead of const

Comment: Possible duplicate of [querySelector in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032004/queryselector-in-typescript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns instance of `Element`. And there is not much [declared](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3652) in the typings for it. In order to fix the error - cast it to more specific type, for example:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#launcher') as HTMLInputElement;
if (element && element.style && element.style.display)
{
    element.style.display = '';
}
```

Basically everything that inherits from [HTMLElement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4570) will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend giving specific types while declaring variables.

For eg: in your case the querySelector returns value of type 'Element|null'
So, you can define your element variable like this

```
const element: Element = document.querySelector('#launcher');
```

Hope this helps.