# How to define data type for queryselector in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to define the data type for query selector in typescript, But I do not know how to define it. I have defined any. But any is not a good way. So, How to define the data type for query selector.

test.ts:

```
public getMatch:any;
public readyCont:any;

this.getMatch = document.querySelector("#exampleId");
this.readyCont = this.getMatch.shadowRoot.querySelector("#matchId");
```

Comment: VScode tells me `getMatch` is of type `Element` when I hover it. You can write `public getMatch:Element;`

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032004/queryselector-in-
typescript , you can cast it as HTMLInputElement

Comment: According to [.querySelector() MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), method returns the first `Element` within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. So you can declare `getMatch` type: `public getMatch: Element`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

querySelector is a generic function. If you don't pass a type into it then it returns an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). Assuming you are querying an HTML document and not anything with SVG elements in it then it is safe to assume that it returns an [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). You can pass this type into the function so you can do:

```
public getMatch:HTMLElement
this.getMatch = document.querySelector<HTMLElement>("#exampleId");
```

However if you know the type of element you are querying then you can be a bit more specific, eg

```
public getMatch:HTMLInputElement
this.getMatch = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>("#exampleId");
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` returns an `HTMLElement` or `null` if he can't find it.

```
public getMatch: HTMLElement | null;
public readyCont: HTMLElement | null;

this.getMatch = document.querySelector("#exampleId");
this.readyCont = this.getMatch.shadowRoot.querySelector("#matchId");
```