# ECMAScript7 async/await inconsistent behavior depending on whether using brackets in arrow function or not

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am experiencing inconsistent behavior in *Google Chrome 60.0.3112.78 (Official Build) (64-bit)* when using modern ES6+ async/await, depending on whether I use brackets in the arrow function that returns a *Promise*. The same happens in Node.js. I am having trouble understanding why.

I understand that this is not how to implement a sleep() function but it is the easiest way to demonstrate. Consider the following example code snippet.

```
function sleep(ms = 0) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async () => {
  console.log('a');
  await sleep(5000);
  console.log('b');
})()
```

As expected, this will write **a** to the console, wait **5 seconds** and then write **b** to the console.

---

Shorter notation using an arrow function to return the *Promise*.

```
const sleep = ms => { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)) }

(async () => {
  console.log('a');
  await sleep(5000);
  console.log('b');
})()
```

As expected this code behaves the same. **a** and **b** are written to the console with a **5000 millisecond** interval in between.

---

The following code **does not work**. The only difference is that I am not wrapping the return of the *Promise* in brackets on the first line.

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

(async () => {
  console.log('a');
  await sleep(5000);
  console.log('b');
})()
```

In this case, await sleep does not work. In fact, this code does absolutely nothing at all. It does not log anything to the console, not **a** and not **b**.

I consider myself fairly experienced but I don't currently understand this. Why do the brackets matter in this particular case? The return value is identical, right? And how come not even the character **a** is console logged?

Somebody please explain to me exactly and specifically why this is the way it is. Is this a bug or do I just need sleep myself?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/5743988)

Comment: @4castle If you refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596/1048572), I recommend to use function *declarations* instead (`function sleep(ms) { return … }`) which don't need a semicolon at all :-)

Answer (score 9):

It's the semicolon after the arrow function that matters. Write

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
//                                                                 ^
```

and it will work. Notice that the next line starts with `(`, which is a syntactically valid continuation, so [ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/1048572) doesn't jump in. Your code is parsed and interpreted as

```
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))(async () => { … })()
```

but the function `sleep` is never called.

Comment: @Matthew They are, but if you want to omit semicolons and let them be automatically inserted where ever possible, you will [need to put one at the *begin*](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) of every line that starts with `(`, `[`, `/`, `+`, `-` or `\``.

Comment: Haha yes, but the obscurity of this bug makes me appreciate the extra keystroke.

Comment: Thanks! You're right I can't believe I missed that. Phew! On a sidenote I actually religiously never use semi colons unless there is no other way and believe you can identify good developers by this habit. But I'm biased. Thanks again! :)

Comment: "The rationale is that it’s easier to always include semicolons than to try to remember when they are or are not required, and thus decreases the possibility of introducing an error."

Comment: @JochemStoel I would have guessed that if you had omitted them in the async function as well :-)

Comment: @Jaime I disagree.  Having to remember every time whether you need to use a semi colon or not  keeps you focused as a developer. It forces you into it. Nothing on auto-pilot.

Comment: @JochemStoel I assume that you waste at least one hour trying to figure out why your code wasn't working as expected. Automatic semicolon insertion (ASI) is considered one of the more controversial features of JavaScript. We should treat ASI as if it didn’t exist.

Comment: @Jaime We just should not forget semicolons. Whether at the end of every line, or the beginning of every line (that starts with parenthesis) does not matter. It's entirely a personal preference, and once you get accustomed to either method you should be able to spot missing ones easily. Or let your linter do it, there are rules for both styles.

Comment: @Bergi, would you mind updating your answer to include OP's code with a leading semicolon before the IIFE?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis No, isn't including the part that was fixed enough?