# How to use Javascript in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think I'm fundamentally misunderstanding how to implement Javascript in my rails app. My understanding was that you throw your Javascript into your `application.js` file and then you can reference elements in your DOM using `jQuery` in order to make an interactive web page.

I just checked through all of my code, and it looks clean (posted below in case I'm wrong). My thought is that I may be putting my Javascript in the wrong place, or I'm missing a dependency somewhere? I found other posts to be mostly unhelpful for me. How do I merge Javascript into my app?

**application.js**

```js
function main() {
  $('.answers-box').hide();
  $('.qaa-box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
  });
}
$(document).ready(main());
```

**page.html.erb**

```html
<div class="qaa-box">
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h4>
  <p class="answers-box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you found this?
[Where to Stick Your JavaScript](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html#locations).

> **Where to Stick Your JavaScript**
>
> Whether you use the Rails asset pipeline or add a `<script>` tag directly to a view, you have to make a choice about where to put any local JavaScript file.
>
> We have a choice of *three* locations for a local JavaScript file:
>
> - the `app/assets/javascripts` folder
> - the `lib/assets/javascripts` folder
> - the `vendor/assets/javascripts` folder
>
> Here are **guidelines** for selecting a location for your scripts:
>
> - Use `app/assets/javascripts` for JavaScript you create for your application.
> - Use `lib/assets/javascripts` for scripts that are shared by many applications *(but use a gem if you can)*.
> - Use `vendor/assets/javascripts` for copies of jQuery plugins, etc., from other developers.
>
> In the *simplest* case, when all your JavaScript files are in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder, there’s nothing more you need to do.
>
> Add JavaScript files anywhere else and you will need to understand how to modify a manifest file.
>
> **Mysterious Manifests**
>   There are two kinds of files in a JavaScript assets folder:
>
> - ordinary JavaScript files
> - manifest files
>     You can also have `CoffeeScript` files and `ERB` files which are variations on *ordinary* JavaScript files.
>
> *Manifest* files have the same .js file extension as ordinary JavaScript files. Manifest files and ordinary JavaScript files can be combined in a single file. This makes manifest files *mysterious*, or at least non-obvious.
>
> The default *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* file is a `manifest file`. It’s a manifest file because it contains directives:
>
> ```
> //= require jquery  
> //= require jquery_ujs  
> //= require_tree .
> ```
>
> Directives tell Sprockets which files should be combined to build a single JavaScript script. Each file that contains manifest directives becomes a single JavaScript script with the same name as the original manifest file. Thus the `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` manifest file *becomes* the `application.js` script.
>
> All scripts in the `app/assets/javascripts` folder are automatically added to the default `application.js` script when the manifest file includes the default *//= require_tree .* directive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is super helpful, and I read through the article you posted, now I know, at least, where to stick my javascript, I'm still having trouble getting it to run though. :/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 5 you may need to add jQuery to your project by adding

`gem 'jquery-rails'`

in your Gemfile, as well as adding

`//= jquery`

to your `app > assets > javascript > application.js` file.

Since Rails 5 uses Turbolinks, you may also need to change the listener

`$(document).ready` to `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(main());`

Adding a `console.log` to the `main` function will help with debugging to see if the event is being fired.

Comment: Okay, so I have the gem. I added //= jquery to my application.js. I tried both `$(document).ready` and the other method and added a `console.log` 

No dice. Its not even firing. What should I do to troubleshoot this? How do I get rails to listen to this?

Comment: In troubleshooting rails, you first want to check any spellings.  Double check your functions, names, variables, etc.  Then restart the rails server.  If those don't work make a very simple jQuery function you know 100% will work, like `$('.qaa-box').on('click', function() { console.log("jQuery fired") });` and place it inside of main. Use that to determine if jQuery is firing events or not

Comment: I did that. It is not firing events. What do I do now?

Comment: Try changing `$(document).on('turbolinks:load ...` to `document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { alert("ok!") });` and see if that works

Comment: this is on the right track. It made the alert "ok!" pop up. Now how should I write my callback to load my function? I tried playing with the above callback with my function and wasn't able to get it to work.

Comment: Easiest way would be to remove the function and place it directly into the body: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f02d9e4cf0038fc1420643255dedc64b

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the parentheses after the function `main()` in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(main();)
```

In addition to this, try the following:

Add the `jquery-rails` gem to your Gemfile (place this in your gem file):

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then run `bundle install`

Then write the following in your `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: You can skip the semi

Comment: You could.. I prefer to keep them there in case I write another function. More reasons to use semicolon after every statement can be found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready()` expects a function, not the result of function call. Instead, you're calling `main()` *before* `DOMReady` event, and passing `undefined` into `$(document).ready()` function.

It should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(main);
```