# Devise `user_signed_in?` inside `.js.erb` file `NoMethodError`

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a code like this in my `app/assets/javascripts/sample.js.erb` file.

```
  var user_signed_in = <%= user_signed_in? %>;
  if(user_signed_in){
      // run code here
  }
```

By the looks of it, with the `.js.erb` file extension. This should work. I am able to use the `user_signed_in?` in the view that uses this JS file. So why?

Comment: try this ` var user_signed_in = "<%= user_signed_in? %>";`

Comment: @Vishal does not work.

Comment: It should work in this way, put `console.log("<%= user_signed_in %>") ` let me know what you get

Comment: I still get the error: `undefined local variable or method `user_signed_in'`.

Comment: shouldn't it be ? `<%= user_signed_in? %>`. Also, can you add this in `application` layout.

Comment: try to use with `"<%  user_signed_in? %>"` instead of `"<%=  user_signed_in? %>"`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Yes right, it should be like this. and he is used that

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna already added it in the application.js file. Still not working. Your suggestion for `<%= user_signed_in? %>` is whats in my question and is not working.

Comment: Tried that `"<% user_signed_in? %>" `. Still not working @Vishal.

Comment: Let me know, what you get when you do `console.log("<% used_signed_in? %>")`   and `console.log('<% "#{user_signed_in?}" %>')`

Comment: I get errors since `user_signed_in?` is an undefined method, according to the error. @Vishal.

Comment: Have you tried using [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) ?

Comment: Were not considering a new gem for this, because we are only using this for one scenario. Anyways, thanks @KedarnagMukanahallipatna.

Comment: Why do you have a _*.js.erb_ file under _app/assets/javascripts/_? Shouldn't you be using it in some view under _app/views/_?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh we have a page where we want to check if a user us signed in when he/she visits it on the JS level. We also could possibly use it on other pages in the future. So we want it to be inside an independent js.erb file.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh hats of to your eyes. i didn't notice that

Comment: Try: `var user_signed_in = <%=raw user_signed_in? %>;`

Comment: @Emu not working.

Comment: @RicardoGreen Basically, why any solutions not working because your are not following the concept of ror, you should not use js.erb file in js folder, "user_signed_in?" is just helper and you can't access outside of view folder. you are trying to access in js folder. that's why it is giving you error. please go and follow the correct structure

Comment: I think you are not following the right structure. Check this [link](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html#locations) which might help you. Also, a similar question was made [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534739/how-to-use-javascript-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make something like this

```
<% if current_user  %>
  <%= link_to "Add New Event",new_event_path %>
<% end %>
```