# What's the best way to find the last non empty value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function where I get the first non empty value in a multidimensionnal array. In my example the first non empty value is B because I through the array by thecolumns first.
Now, in this function, I need to get also the last non empty value. In my example "C" is the last non empty value. Because "C" is in the furthest column. 
So... How I can get C in my function ?

Thank you !

```js
function findFirstAndLastValue (timeline) {
  for (var col = 0; col < timeline[0].length; col++) {
      for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
        if (timeline[row][col] != '') {
          return [row, col];
        }
      }
    }
}

function getFirstAndLastValue() {
    var projectTl = [
      ['','','A','A','',''],
      ['','B','B','','',''],
      ['','','','','C',''],
      ['','','D','D','','']
    ] 

    var position = findFirstAndLastValue(projectTl);
    console.log(position)
}

getFirstAndLastValue();
```

Comment: why not try reversing the loop so you start from the end.

Comment: You cannot use return here. And you could better run backwards

Comment: Your code is missing a few semicolons.

Comment: @Amy irrelevant. Semicolons are only mandatory in inline handlers and code that is to be minified.

Comment: @mplungjan [is it irrelevant?  for the sake of consistency and readability, i disagree with you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/444082/47589)

Comment: Feel free to disagree. The semicolons have no bearing on the issue at hand.

Comment: @mplungjan i never said they did.  It's called "making an observation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to loop your cols from the last index:**

```
for (var col = timeline[0].length - 1; col > 0; col--)
```

```js
function findFirstAndLastValue(timeline) {
 var result = {
 "first": [],
 "last": []
 };
  first: for (var col = 0; col < timeline[0].length; col++) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
      if (timeline[row][col] != '') {
         result.first = [row, col];
         break first;
      }
    }
  }
  
  last: for (var col = timeline[0].length - 1; col > 0; col--) {
    for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
      if (timeline[row][col] != '') {
        result.last = [row, col];
        break last;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

function getFirstAndLastValue() {

  var projectTl = [
    ['', '', 'A', 'A', '', ''],
    ['', 'B', 'B', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', 'C', ''],
    ['', '', 'D', 'D', '', '']
  ]

  var position = findFirstAndLastValue(projectTl);
  console.log(position);
}

getFirstAndLastValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your exact same code, but making it loop backwards instead of forwards gets you the desired result.. you could also [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the array, or take any number of "functional" approaches.

```js
function findFirstAndLastValue (timeline) {
  for (var col = timeline[0].length; col--;) {
      for (var row = 4; row--;) {
        if (timeline[row][col] != '') {
          return [row, col];
        }
      }
    }
}

var projectTl = [
  ['','','A','A','',''],
  ['','B','B','','',''],
  ['','','','','C',''],
  ['','','D','D','','']
] 

  var position = findFirstAndLastValue(projectTl);
  console.log(position)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce()` method and return one object as a result.

```js
var projectTl = [
  ['', '', 'A', 'A', '', ''],
  ['', 'B', 'B', '', '', ''],
  ['', '', '', '', 'C', ''],
  ['', '', 'D', 'D', '', '']
]

const findInArr = data => {
  let temp = {
    first: null,
    last: null
  }
  return data.reduce((r, arr) => {
    arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
      if (e) {
        if (temp.last == null || i > temp.last) {
          temp.last = i
          r.last = e
        }
        if (temp.first == null || i < temp.first) {
          temp.first = i;
          r.first = e;
        }
      }
    })
    return r;
  }, Object.assign({}, temp))
}

console.log(findInArr(projectTl))
```

Comment: Why this `Object.assign({}, temp)` and not only `temp`? Why create a new object for the `initialValue`?  Curiosity :-)

Comment: One is for index other one for values, also they are passed by reference so we need to create shallow copy.

Comment: I know that, my concern is about the creation of a new object calling `Object.assign({}, temp)` rather than just passing `temp` as an `initialValue`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for one liner in js, you can do it like this

```js
// For Single arrays | get last non empty value 
let your_array = ['','A','B','','C','', ''];
let last_non_empty_value = your_array.filter(item => item).pop(-1);
console.log(last_non_empty_value);

// for Getting Last Non Empty values only from multi-dimensional arrays
let a = [
    ['', '', 'A', 'E', '', ''],
    ['', 'B', 'C', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', '', 'D', ''],
    ['', '', 'F', 'G', '', '']
];
let last_values = a.map(item=>item.filter(item=>item).pop());
console.log(last_values);
```