# TypeError: Math.floor() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js Discord Bot, written in discord.js, and I want to make a turn based fighting system, so I made a damage calculation function.

```
var damage = parseFloat( Math.floor( Math.random() * skill.dmg/5 ) + skill.dmg )
//some other factors, none causing the error
damage = Math.floor( damage )
```

the code is quite simple, but it's erroring with a

> TypeError: Math.floor(...) is not a function

I've checked every other post, done what they did, but nothing worked,
I've cleared the cache, I've checked for the camelCase, ...

What should I do?

The main function code:

```
var damage = parseFloat( Math.floor( Math.random() * skill.dmg/5 ) + skill.dmg )
damage += weapons[ user.inv.armor.weapon ].damage
var crit = ( ( Math.floor( Math.random() * 100 ) + skill.crit ) > 100 ? ( Math.random() + 1 ).toFixed( 1 ) : 1 )
damage *= crit
if ( !tags.includes( 'ignorant' ) ) {
    damage -= enemy.stats.res
    damage *= parseFloat( "0." + ( 100 - enemy.res[ tags[1] ] ) )
    damage -= shields[ enemy.inv.armor.shield ].res
}
damage = Math.floor( damage )damage = Math.floor( damage )
( monster ? enemy.hp -= damage : enemy.profile.hp -= damage )
```

Comment: That's strange. What version of Node JS are you using?

Comment: Try inspecting `Math`. It may have been redefined or something at some point.

Comment: This might help: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/5275475bf10c601cb4002593

Comment: Node.sj v9.10.0
But I've used Math.floor() before in the same code

Comment: @PraveenKumar I already looked at it, as I said, I cleared the cache and everything

Comment: @Dia.Frost Can you post the full code by [edit]ing the question? We can take a look if there's a redefinition of `Math` somewhere?

Comment: Are you *sure* that's where the error happens? That error message is telling you that the *return value* from `Math.floor()` is not a function. What's on the next line after `damage = Math.floor( damage )`? That line is missing a semicolon, so the next line could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: I offer the suggestion that you really should get used to using semicolons, one way or the other.

Comment: @Pointy it was the line after, I had a *( ... )* after it, causing it to think of it as a Function

Comment: Exactly!  Semicolons are friendly and they won't hurt you.

Comment: You really shouldn't call `parseFloat` on a number

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Math.floor` does indeed exist, it's not a problem with `Math`. If `Math.floor` wasn't a function the error would be:

`TypeError: Math.floor is not a function`

But you're getting

```
TypeError: Math.floor(...) is not a function
```

Which means you're doing:

```
Math.floor(damage)();
```

So post the code after `damage = Math.floor( damage )` which most likely will be `(...)`, so we can pinpoint the exact error.

```js
try {
  Math.floors(5); // Added extra S on purpose
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);
}


try {
  Math.floor(5)();
} catch(e){
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

**Update**

The error was triggered in the following code:

```
damage = Math.floor( damage ) 
( monster ? enemy.hp -= damage : enemy.profile.hp -= damage )
```

What you were doing, is **calling** the result of `Math.floor` which is a number.

```
damage = Math.floor( damage ); // ; this bad boy was all that was missing.
monster ? enemy.hp -= damage : enemy.profile.hp -= damage;
```

This is why semicolons are important!

[Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

**yes, I absolutely do**

Comment: I had it like this:
`damage = Math.floor( damage )
( monster ? enemy.hp -= damage : enemy.profile.hp -= damage )`
but I realised after @Pointy's comment

Comment: I will add that to my answer, so It will help someone in the future. Don't forget to add full code, or a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example so we can help you! https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I've added the erroring part as well, so people can see where the mistake was