# Javascript. Adding Arrays into an Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I solved **Challenge 16** with no problem. I also found an answer for **Challenge 17** but I don't understand why I can only use square brackets for adding property into an object like this: `loopNumbers[nestedArr[i][0]] = nestedArr[i][1]`

So, my questions are:

1. Why can't I use dot notation like this?: `loopNumbers.nestedArr[i][0] = nestedArr[i][1]`
   If I use dot notation, then it says `Type Error on line 120: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
2. How come I don't need to put semicolon after the line of code `loopNumbers[nestedArr[i][0]] = nestedArr[i][1]`?

> Below are the challenges.

---

**Challenge 16**

> You are provided with an empty array called `nestedArr`. Using a for loop, add 5 sub-arrays to `nestedArr`, with each nested array containing the string 'loop' concatenated with the corresponding index in `nestedArr` as it's first element, and just the index as it's second element. Example of a subarray - `['loop3', 3]`

```
My answer:

let nestedArr = [];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  nestedArr.push(['loop'+i, i]);
}
console.log(nestedArr);
```

---

**Challenge 17**

> Create a variable called `loopNumbers` and initialize it to an empty object literal. Using a for loop, iterate through `nestedArr` from the previous challenge. For each iteration of your loop, assign a new property to `loopNumbers` where the property name is the first element in each nested array in `nestedArr` and the value is the second element.

```
My answer:

let loopNumbers = {};
for (let i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i++) {
       loopNumbers[nestedArr[i][0]] = nestedArr[i][1]
   }
console.log(loopNumbers);
```

Comment: semi colon line breaks are optional in javascript due to automatic semi colon insertion with caveat that there are some code sequences that will break if they aren't used. Best practice is always use them

Comment: `loopNumbers.nestedArr` means "access property with name `nestedArr` on `loopNumbner`". That's not what you want so you should not do it. Consider a similar problem with math operators. `1 + 2 * 3` is different than `(1 + 2) * 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: several times I use "get" when it's more of "access" or "consider". So yes, I'm saying "get this thing" and I'm not necessarily meaning read it's value, but instead "we're doing something here". Just roll with it ok?

In `js`, arrays are accessed as "get entry at `index` of `array`":

```
array[index]
```

and objects are accessed as "get property named `property` from `object`":

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

what you're trying to do is "get property from `object` named by entry `index` of `array`". That's something you CAN do. But what you actually did was ask for something a little different.

`loopNumbers.nestedArr[i][0]` *means* "get property `nestedArr` from object `loopNumbers` and from that get entry at index `i` and from that get entry at index `0`.

to get the property of `loopNumbers` that is named by the `0`th entry of the `i`th entry of nestedArr, you have to start by getting the `i`th entry of nestedArr

```
nestedArr[i]
```

And then you want entry 0

```
nestedArr[i][0]
```

Now this is not a property you can just use directly because as said before `loopNumbers.nestedArr` tries to get a property called `nestedArr` from the object `loopNumbers`, which does not exist. The only way to get the property named by the value stored in `nestedArr[i][0]` from the object called `loopNumbers` is with square brackets as

```
loopNumbers[nestedArr[i][0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons are optional in javascript but it's recommended to always add them in order to avoid ambiguities on several cases (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)).

For adding a property, you can use dot if the argument is static so something like :

```
loopnumbers.myproperty = 3
```

But as `nestedArr[i][0]` is not static, you need to put the brackets.

Comment: Thank you fazega! How do I know the argument is static of not in JavaScript?? I know in Java, I used like `static int num = 3;`

Comment: By 'static' I mean something that is not interpreted, that is to say a word. You can't do loopnumbers.variable = something.