# change CSS within for loop

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following:

```
function validateInput(departmentArray) {
  let isValid = true
  const array = Object.keys(departmentArray)

  for(let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    keyname = array[i]
    if (departmentArray[keyname] === '') {
        const errorMsg = `Missing \'${keyname}\' on form`
        isValid = false

        $('#`keyname`').toggleClass('warningBox')

    }
  }
  return isValid
}
```

The `keyname` that errors out due to being empty needs to be given a red box around in the HTML. I have tried

```
$('#`keyname`').toggleClass('warningBox')
```

and variations thereof. How do I address the keyname with JQuery to be able to change its CSS ?

Comment: Are you trying to add the string `keyname`, or add the value of `keyname`? Please clarify your intent.

Comment: Just concat them: ```$("#" + keyname)```

Comment: Why aren't you using semicolons?

Comment: semicolons are optional. I tried concatenating them and it didn't work for me. I want the value of keyname

Comment: While optional, they serve a purpose and not using them can lead to bugs if not used.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript#444082  And given that you should always be using a minifier for productional javascript, not using semicolons would cause bugs, since minifiers make everything a single line.

Comment: @Taplar thank you for the link and explanation. Just learned something new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use a template literal, then your syntax is incorrect.

```
$(`#${keyname}`).toggleClass('warningBox');
```

```js
var keyname = 'me'
var test = `#${keyname}`;
console.log(test);
```

Comment: This did it. Had the template literal incorrect. Thanks