# Why am I getting an infinite loop error inp5.js?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, p5.js

With a simple for loop I can trigger a potential infinite loop exception in the [p5.js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/charlie-openschool/sketches/kGLK95CWa)

```
function setup() {
  var cnt = 0;
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  for (i = 0; i < 80000; i++) {
    console.log(cnt++);
  }
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("done in " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
}
```

Gives me output:

> Exiting potential infinite loop at line 5. To disable loop protection: add "// noprotect" to your code
>   done in 501 milliseconds

Which is not surprising as I see that the threshold has been increased to 500ms in [p5.js-web-editor issues 174](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-web-editor/issues/174)

What is surprising, at least to me, is that if I remove any of the semicolons the potential infinite loop is not detected after 500ms and my loop completes.

For example:

```
function setup() {
  var cnt = 0 // no semicolon here..
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  for (i = 0; i < 80000; i++) {
    console.log(cnt++);
  }
  var endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("done in " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds");
}
```

Gives me output:

> 79999
>
> done in 1737 milliseconds

My question is, why does removing a semicolon break the p5.js web editor's infinite loop detection?

Comment: What editor is warning you about infinite loops?

Comment: The p5.js online editor

Comment: I don't see any warnings in the P5.js editor. When I run your code I see a black rectangle.

Comment: I reran the code and it still failed. I [screengrabbed](https://imgur.com/a/JeivCTl) the editor so you can see the error. If it doesn't happen in yours, then is it something wrong with my computer?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Your code looks fine, and works fine for me, assuming it's supposed to create a black rectangle. I suppose if your computer was extremely slow it might cause this error, but I would not think a 400x400 nested loop would cause any problems. If you measure how the time (using the `millis()` function), how long does your `setup()` function take?

Comment: 3.8 sec without semicolon (no error) 1.5 sec with semicolon (error)

Comment: Here is the [sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/BWcoder/sketches/akgp1nYR5). Remove any semicolon to fix the error.

Comment: I still don't see the error in the sketch you just linked.

Comment: Well then, there is nothing I can do besides just removing a semicolon and moving on.

Comment: Try removing code until you get down to the minimum code that shows the error. This will help you ask a better question and may also help you understand your own code better. For example some if conditionals are very hard to understand.

Comment: For example what is the intention of if (i % (1 / (n % 1)) < 1) and does it have any connection to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [p5.js web editor](https://editor.p5js.org/) can throw an exception when it detects what might be an infinite loop in a running sketch.

The logic the web editor uses to detect infinite loops is quite simple, if a loop executes [for more than 500ms](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-web-editor/issues/174) the exception is thrown. This exception may be confusing as the loop may have been almost ready to complete at the moment the exception was thrown with this message:

> Exiting potential infinite loop

The word **potential** is important for understanding the message. This line of code will trigger the exception:

```
while(true);
```

but any finite loop that executes for more than 500ms will also trigger the message.

In cases where we know a loop is not infinite and we also know that it may take longer than 500ms to complete we can add a noprotect comment to disable infinite loop protection:

```
var cnt = 0;
// noprotect
while(cnt < 80000)console.log(cnt++);
```

This code will log the numbers 0 to 79999. Before adding the noprotect comment be sure and review the code carefully. A small mistake can turn a finite loop into an infinite loop:

```
var cnt = 0;
// noprotect
while(cnt < 80000)console.log(cnt);
```

By forgetting to increment `cnt` we have created an infinite loop that will not be detected by the p5.js web editor. This loop will run until the browser detects it and prompts the user to stop it or wait.

The last part of the question asks why removing a semicolon at the end of a line changes the loop protect behavior. The simple answer is the editor must add instrumentation in order to provide the detection. Missing semicolons cause the editor to not correctly instrument the code. It is a good practice to end javascript statements with a semicolon. See answers to [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/444080/1978785)

**Summary**

- The p5.js web editor can help you avoid long running loops
- Use a `noprotect` comment for intentional long running loops
- use semicolons to end javascript statements