# How to show/hide a drop-down by clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a drop-down element with only one option below.
I stuck when I need to show/hide this option.

HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" title="Some title" type="button">
    <span id="spanId" title="Some other title">Some text</span>
</div>
```

`<i>` -is the image drop-down button.

CSS:

```
#div1 {
    cursor: pointer;
    /*styles, which are not related to the issue*/
}
#spanId {
    display: none;
    /*some other styles*/
}
#spanId :hover {
    background: #e7edf4;
}
```

So, the span is hidden. I can show it, but after that it is remaining visible for ever and I`m not able to hide it.

JS/JQuery:

```
let visible = false
const toggleButton = $('#div1')
const dropDownBtn = $('#spanId')
const someOtherButton = $('#someId')

toggleButton.click(() => {
    dropDownBtn.css("display", "block")
    visible = true
})

if(visible == true){
    $(document).click(() => {
       dropDownBtn.css("display", "none")
       visible = false
    })
}

dropDownBtn.click(() => {
    someOtherButton.click()
})
```

Also I tried to do it with `<select>` , bu did not succeed. Also try `show() & hide()` methods of jQuery. I really can`t realize where am I wrong.

Comment: Also, unrelated.  [Do you recommend using semicolons after every statement in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444080/do-you-recommend-using-semicolons-after-every-statement-in-javascript)

Comment: Also, the logic in the `if(visible == true)` is never going to happen, as visible is false on page load, and only changes to true once a click event happens.  Which is well past the point that conditional runs

Comment: you never closed `<i class="fa fa-plus-square" title="Some title" type="button">`

Answer (score 1):

Simply toggle a class:

```js
div1.addEventListener('click', () => spanId.classList.toggle('visible'))
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!div1.contains(e.target)) spanId.classList.remove('visible')
})
```

```css
#spanId { display: none; }
#spanId.visible { display: block; }
```

```html
<div id="div1">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square" title="Some title">ICON HERE</i>
    <span id="spanId" title="Some other title">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Also your code had errors. The `<i>` was not closed properly, and `i` does not have a `type` attribute. The Javascript logical error you made was already mentioned in your comments.

Or, if you insist on jQuery:

```js
$(div1).on('click', () => $(spanId).toggleClass('visible'))
```

```css
#spanId {
  display: none;
}

#spanId.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <i class="fa fa-plus-square" title="Some title">ICON HERE</i>
  <span id="spanId" title="Some other title">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code resolved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you can advise how to drop-up the span, clicking outside the toggle button?
Like this:
`$(document).click(() => {}`

Comment: @TirelessCoder Done.